# How to initialize a dict with keys from a list and empty value in Python?

Tags: dictionary, python

I'd like to get from this:

```
keys = [1,2,3]
```

to this:

```
{1: None, 2: None, 3: None}
```

Is there a pythonic way of doing it?

This is an ugly way to do it:

```
>>> keys = [1,2,3]
>>> dict([(1,2)])
{1: 2}
>>> dict(zip(keys, [None]*len(keys)))
{1: None, 2: None, 3: None}
```

Comment: Do you intend for the dictionary to have `None` values for all keys? If so, why not use a `set` instead? The only reason that comes to mind for using a `dict` instead of `set` in this case is if you want to iterate the structure in insertion order.

Answer (score 557, accepted):

[`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) directly solves the problem:

```
>>> dict.fromkeys([1, 2, 3, 4])
{1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None}
```

This is actually a classmethod, so it works for dict-subclasses (like `collections.defaultdict`) as well.

The optional second argument, which defaults to `None`, specifies the value to use for the keys. Note that the *same object* will be used for each key, which can cause problems with mutable values:

```
>>> x = dict.fromkeys([1, 2, 3, 4], [])
>>> x[1].append('test')
>>> x
{1: ['test'], 2: ['test'], 3: ['test'], 4: ['test']}
```

If this is unacceptable, see [How can I initialize a dictionary whose values are distinct empty lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509721) for a workaround.

Comment: Be careful with initializing to something mutable:  If you call, e.g., `dict.fromkeys([1, 2, 3], [])`, all of the keys are mapped to the same list, and modifying one will modify them all.

Comment: Initializing with `{k:[] for k in [1, 2, 3]}` is still safe though.

Comment: @charleslparker are you sure of this? I tried to initialize a dictionary from a list, then changed the first element in the list (mutate it). The dictionary keys weren't affected.

Comment: @ReslanTinawi It's not about the keys. If you would add something to the list corresponding to the first key, then it would also be added to the lists belonging to the other keys; because they all reference the same list.

Answer (score 361):

Use a [dict comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817):

```
>>> keys = [1,2,3,5,6,7]
>>> {key: None for key in keys}
{1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 5: None, 6: None, 7: None}
```

The value expression is evaluated each time, so this can be used to create a dict with separate lists (say) as values:

```
>>> x = {key: [] for key in [1, 2, 3, 4]}
>>> x[1] = 'test'
>>> x
{1: 'test', 2: [], 3: [], 4: []}
```

Comment: I believe it was backported to 2.7

Comment: This is nice and doesn't suffer from the reference issue that the accepted answer does.

Comment: This also allows you to assign a default value (e.g. `False`).

Comment: This is the cleanest, most Pythonic way in Python3 IMO

Comment: it works in python 2.7, I am really happy every time I can use a list comprehension, makes me feel smart.

Comment: Using a dict-comp also allows the value to be the result of calling a function (which could be passed the key as an argument, if desired) — so is a very powerful mechanism.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509721.

Answer (score 83):

```
dict.fromkeys(keys, None)
```

Comment: awesome, i wanted empty lists, ``dict.fromkeys(keys, [])``

Comment: @muon That is almost certainly not what you want, see [charleslparker comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241891/how-to-initialize-a-dict-with-keys-from-a-list-and-empty-value-in-python#comment25131847_2241904).

Comment: Works in Python version 2.6.6.

Comment: Beware: this will initialize dict with all keys points to same single value

Answer (score 22):

A [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951) can be used to build a list of key-value pairs, which can then be passed to the `dict` constructor. Thus:

```
>>> keys = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
>>> d = dict([(key, []) for key in keys])
>>> d
{'d': [], 'c': [], 'a': [], 'b': []}
```

The value expression is evaluated each time, creating separate lists in the above example:

```
>>> d['a'].append('test')
>>> d
{'d': [], 'c': [], 'a': ['test'], 'b': []}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: the name `keyDict` is misleading, as the first line of code returns a `set`, not a `dict`.

Comment: They probably will be mapped to the same list though

Answer (score 15):

Simply iterate and add the values to an empty dictionary:

```
d = {}
for i in keys:
    d[i] = None
```

Answer (score 9):

In *many* workflows where you want to attach a default / initial value for arbitrary keys, you don't *need* to hash each key individually ahead of time. You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: None)

print(d[1])  # None
print(d[2])  # None
print(d[3])  # None
```

This is more efficient, it saves having to hash all your keys at instantiation. Moreover, `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`, so there's usually no need to convert back to a regular dictionary.

For workflows where you *require* controls on permissible keys, you can use [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) as per the accepted answer:

```
d = dict.fromkeys([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because it's fun how the [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor works nicely with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), you can [`repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) the default value and `zip` it to the keys:

```py
from itertools import repeat

keys = [1, 2, 3]
default_value = None

d = dict(zip(keys, repeat(default_value)))
print(d)
```

Will give:

```
{1: None, 2: None, 3: None}
```

---

`repeat` creates an infinite iterator of the element passed to it but as `zip` stops on the shortest iterable all works well.