# initialize dict with keys,values from two list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241891/how-to-initialize-a-dict-with-keys-from-a-list-and-empty-value-in-python) link

But how do I initialize the dictionary as well ?

say two list

```
 keys = ['a','b','c','d'] 
 values = [1,2,3,4] 
 dict = {}
```

I want initialize `dict` with `keys` & `values`

Comment: If you had actually read the *question*, you'd have seen that the code shown there solves your problem.

Comment: How do i give `b` as a list in `dict.fromkeys(a,b)`

Comment: You don't, but at the end of the question the OP shows the code `dict(zip(keys, [None]*len(keys)))`, which is essentially the same as the accepted answer on your question here (`[None]*len(keys)` builds a list that contains `len(keys)` times `None` ).

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
d = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

(Please don't call your `dict` `dict`, that's a built-in name.)

Answer (score 20):

In Python 2.7 and python 3, you can also make a dictionary comprehension

```
d = {key:value for key, value in zip(keys, values)}
```

Although a little verbose, I found it more clear, as you clearly see the relationship.