# Issue with matching keys of dictionary to index of a data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a `testing_df` organized like so:

`# Use the arrays to create a dataframe
testing_df =pd.DataFrame(test_array,columns=['transaction_id','product_id'])`

`# Split the product_id's for the testing data
testing_df.set_index(['transaction_id'],inplace=True)
print(testing_df.head(n=5))`

`transaction_id       product_id

001                      (P01,)
002                  (P01, P02)
003             (P01, P02, P09)
004                  (P01, P03)
005             (P01, P03, P05)`

I then performed some calculations on it and created a dictionary to store the results:

`# Initialize a dictionary to store the matches
matches = {}`

`# Return the product combos values that are of the appropriate length and the strings match
for transaction_id,i in enumerate (testing_df['product_id']):
    recommendation = None
    recommended_count = 0`

```
for k, count in product_combos.items():
    k = list(k)
    if len(i)+1 == len(k) and count >= recommended_count:
        for product in i:
            if product in k: 
                k.remove(product)
        if len(k) == 1:
            recommendation = k[0]
            recommended_count = count
matches[transaction_id] = recommendation
```

`print(matches)
[out]
{0: 'P09', 1: 'P09', 2: 'P06', 3: 'P09', 4: 'P09', 5: 'P09'}`

The problem I have is that the keys of the matches dictionary should be 001,002,003,004,005 etc. - corresponding to the index of the test_df which is 001-100.

The second issue I have is that I would like to fill another dictionary (recommendations) with the keys being 001-100. I would like the fill the values from matches into this dict by matching the key-values. any help would be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So inside your for loop when using enumerate, your transaction_id will just be an integer. When you use that as the key in your dictionary it will show up as 1 and not 001. If you really want to work around that, you will have to convert it to a string, so instead of doing

```
matches[transaction_id]=recommendation
```

do

```
matches[str(transaction_id).zfill(3)]=recommendation
```

Or you could do a for loop over your index so something like

```
for ind in df.index
```

I'm not sure what you mean with your second question. To create an empty dictionary from your transaction ids just do

```
dict.fromkeys(list(df.index))
```

as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241891/how-to-initialize-a-dict-with-keys-from-a-list-and-empty-value-in-python)

Comment: Hello thanks for replying when i use matches[str(transaction_id).zfill(3)]
 in the code i get the error as KeyError: '000'

Comment: Are you calling matches[str(transaction_id).zfill(3)] before assigning it? I mean of course you need to do

matches[str(transaction_id).zfill(3)]=recommendation

Comment: Ok! i'm getting my values as 000-100 where as they should be starting from 001 as there is no key such as 000

Comment: well then add +1 as in
matches[str(transaction_id+1).zfill(3)]=recommendation