# Appending Elements to a Dictionary from a text file and Setting them to None [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I was wanting to append strings from a text file (line by line) and then set these strings equal to a None value. Is there a way to default each of these Values to None?

I.e.
Text File:

```
Hello
World
```

Dictionary:

```
{"Hello":None, "World":None}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you'd want a dictionary of `None`s.... But here you go

```
Dictionary={}

with open(FILE, "rt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        Dictionary[line.strip()]=None
```

Answer (score 0):

@KJTHoward's answer works well. If you want, there's also a built-in method to do just that called `dict.fromkeys()`. See [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241891/how-to-initialize-a-dict-with-keys-from-a-list-and-empty-value-in-python).

```
with open("path/to/file", "r") as f:
    my_dict = dict.fromkeys([line.strip() for line in f.readlines()])
```

Or a clean dict comprehension way:

```
with open("path/to/file", "r") as f:
    my_dict = {key: None for key in [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]}
```