# How to intialize multiple dictionaries in a single line, and intialize them with a list of keys as an input parameter in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, declare

I have 8 dictionaries intialized in the same way

```
dicc_1={"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0, "Height":0, "All":0}
dicc_2={"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0, "Height":0, "All":0}    
dicc_3={"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0, "Height":0, "All":0}
dicc_4={"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0, "Height":0, "All":0}
dicc_5={"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0, "Height":0, "All":0}
dicc_6={"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0, "Height":0, "All":0}
dicc_7={"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0, "Height":0, "All":0}
dicc_8={"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0, "Height":0, "All":0}
```

Question1:
Is there a better way to do this? Because if I need more dictionaries it will make the script very large
It would be nice if there is a solution like this:

```
dicc_1,dicc_2,dicc_3,dicc_4,dicc_5,dicc_6,dicc_7,dicc_8={"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0, "Height":0, "All":0} * 8
```

But it doesn't work

Question 2:
Is there a way to change the keys if I pass a list of keys? Like this function that doesn't work too

```
def myFunc(ListOfKeys):
   dicc_1,dicc_2,dicc_3,dicc_4,dicc_5,dicc_6,dicc_7,dicc_8={ListOfKeys[0]:0,ListOfKeys[1]:0,ListOfKeys[2]:0, ListOfKeys[3]:0, ListOfKeys[4]:0} * 8
   "Do stuff with dictionaries"
   "Return all dictionaries"
```

So this evaluation:

```
myFunc(ListOfKeys=["Area","Age","Weight","Height","All"])
```

Would intialize dictionaries in this way:

```
dicc_1={"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0,"Height":0,"All":0}
dicc_2={"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0,"Height":0,"All":0}
dicc_3={"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0,"Height":0,"All":0}
dicc_4={"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0,"Height":0,"All":0}
dicc_5={"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0,"Height":0,"All":0}
dicc_6={"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0,"Height":0,"All":0}
dicc_7={"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0,"Height":0,"All":0}
dicc_8={"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0,"Height":0,"All":0}
```

And this evaluation:

```
myFunc(ListOfKeys=["Car","Train","Ship"])
```

Would intialize dictionaries in this way:

```
dicc_1={"Car":0,"Train":0,"Ship":0}
dicc_2={"Car":0,"Train":0,"Ship":0}    
dicc_3={"Car":0,"Train":0,"Ship":0}
dicc_4={"Car":0,"Train":0,"Ship":0}
dicc_5={"Car":0,"Train":0,"Ship":0}
dicc_6={"Car":0,"Train":0,"Ship":0}
dicc_7={"Car":0,"Train":0,"Ship":0}
dicc_8={"Car":0,"Train":0,"Ship":0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Own Answer1. Thanks to: [Python - Initializing Multiple Lists/Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402646/python-initializing-multiple-lists-line)

```
dicc_1, dicc_2, dicc_3, dicc_4, dicc_5, dicc_6, dicc_7, dicc_8= ({"Area":0,"Age":0,"Weight":0, "Height":0, "All":0} for i in range(8))
```

Own Answer2. Thanks to: [How to initialize a dict with keys from a list and empty value in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241891/how-to-initialize-a-dict-with-keys-from-a-list-and-empty-value-in-python)

```
def myFunc(ListofKeys):
    dicc_1, dicc_2, dicc_3, dicc_4, dicc_5, dicc_6, dicc_7, dicc_8 =((dict.fromkeys(ListofKeys,0))  for i in range(8))
    dicc_out={"dicc_1":dicc_1,"dicc_2":dicc_2,"dicc_3":dicc_3,"dicc_4":dicc_4,"dicc_5":dicc_5,"dicc_6":dicc_6,"dicc_7":dicc_7,"dicc_8":dicc_8}
    return(dicc_out)
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new using StackOverflow and I edited the question and I lost an interesting answer that someone left here. I apologyze for that