# initialize python dictionary containing a strings and lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

What's the best way to initialize (e.g. before a loop) a dictionary that will contain strings and a list in each item?

For instance:

```
dict = [("string1", [1,2]), ("string2", [5,6]),..]
```

So:

```
dict["string1"]
```

returns:

```
[1,2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't call a variable dict (or list, or set, etc) because it "covers up" existing functions and prevents you from using them.

```
data = {
    "string1": [1,2],
    "string2": [5,6]
}

print data["string1"]    # => [1,2]
```

If you're a bit of a masochist, you can also try

```
data = dict([("string1",[1,2]), ("string2", [5,6])])
```

or (per cval's example)

```
data = dict(zip(strings, numbers))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strings = ["string1","string2"]
numbers = [[1, 2], [5, 6]]
data = {k:v for k,v in zip(strings, numbers)}
```

And I don't recommend using reserved words (such as `dict`) as variable names.

Comment: Doesn't work as is - strings and strs are not the same variable, same for numbers and nums.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the `list` to the `dict()` function, it'll return a `dictionary`, and never use `dict` as a variable name:

```
>>> dic = [("string1", [1,2]), ("string2", [5,6])]
>>> dict(dic)
{'string2': [5, 6], 'string1': [1, 2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7 and Python 3, [dict comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension):

```
data = {entry[0]: entry[1] for entry in data}
```

or unpack your structures:

```
data = {k: v for (k, v) in data}
```

Python 2.6 and before, generator expression:

```
data = dict((entry[0], entry[1]) for entry in data)
```

or again unpack:

```
data = dict((k, v) for (k, v) in data)
```

Since your data is already in the form of (key, value) sequences, you can just generate a dict in one go by passing the structure to the dict type without an explicit dict or generator expression:

```
dict(data)
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I don't think you need to use a generator expression if the data are already zipped together. `dict(data)` should suffice.