# Python Ordered Dictionary to regular Dictionary

Tags: python

I have something like

```
[('first', 1), ('second', 2), ('third', 3)]
```

and i want  a built in function to make something like

```
{'first': 1, 'second': 2, 'third': 3}
```

Is anyone aware of a built-in python function that provides that instead of having a loop to handle it?

Needs to work with python >= 2.6

Comment: Your input is not an ordered dictionary. It's a list of tuples. Do you want to preserve the order of entries or not?

Comment: Are you using `collections.OrderedDict` or not?

Comment: @TimPietzcker  I called __dict__ on a inspect.getframeinfo(frame)

Comment: @jamylak look at above comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) can take a list of tuples and convert them to key-value pairs.

```
>>> lst = [('first', 1), ('second', 2), ('third', 3)]
>>> dict(lst)
{'second': 2, 'third': 3, 'first': 1}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just apply `dict()` to the list:

```
In [2]: dict([('first', 1), ('second', 2), ('third', 3)])
Out[2]: {'first': 1, 'second': 2, 'third': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not as much elegant/simple as `dict(my_list)` proposed by Volatility's answer...

I would also suggest:

```
my_list = [('first', 1), ('second', 2), ('third', 3)]
my_dict = {k:v for k,v in my_list}
```

It's more useful when you have to filter some elements from the original sequence.

```
my_list = [('first', 1), ('second', 2), ('third', 3)]
my_dict = {k:v for k,v in my_list if k!='third'}
```

or

```
my_dict = {k:v for k,v in my_list if test_value(v)} # test_value being a function return bool
```

as comments says it only works for python >= 2.7

Comment: any rason why you would suggest this way over the other ways and do you know if this will work in python >= 2.6

Comment: Not over the dict(my_list) that I find most pythonic. But I am/was using list and dict comprehension most of the time, so I do use it for python >= 2.7. I suggest tis one cause most of the time there are condition on the elements that are gonna make the final dictionary, and the dict comprenhension and list comprehension mechanism makes the filtering really easy `my_dict = {k:v for k,v in my_list if k != 'third'}`. I'm adding some other examples to the questions.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use this in this scenario. `dict(...)` is faster, looks better and works on every Python. This **only** works on >= 2.7

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot, I will keep this in mind because it does keep the ability to filter some things that i dont want to copy into the new dict which could be large and a waste of memory and so on.

Comment: @WojonsTech yep, only if you have things to filter. But like jamylak says in the present case dict(...) is straight way to go. jamylak is  right about the 2.6 limitation, it is possible at >= 2.7. This question is a good reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension

Comment: @StephaneRolland I cant use it in this project but i wont forget this trick, I had a feeeling it would not work in 2.6, I had to clear up something simular to it to get the code base for this project to run n 2.6, and the only reason i care about 2.6 is this runs on clients servers were i cant force them to upgrade.

Comment: Another way to filter: `my_dict  = dict(filter(lambda val: val if val[0] != 'second' else  None, my_list))`

Comment: @Stepane Rolland While filtering is not the case, dictionary appreciation is more efficient when you create dictionary values "on the fly", e.g. {x: x**2 for x in xrange(100)} is faster than dict((x, x**2) for x in xrange(100)).
Dictionary appreciation is althouugh more efficient when filtering dictionaries

Comment: @volcano dictionary comprehension == dictionary appreciation ? I didn't know the term 'appreciation'.

Comment: OK, sorry, my bad - with fixed terminology the comment still stands