# How to replace r'\xb0' with r'\260'

Tags: python, unicode, replace, character

How can be replaced in string these characters:  r'\xb0' with r'\260', I have tried it to do with:

```
test = u'\xb0C'
test = test.encode('latin1')
test = test.replace(r'\xb0', r'\260')
```

But it doesn't work. The problem is, that I must to write the data into a file in octal format (e.g. '\260C') and not in hex format etc.

Comment: You don't want to replace `r'\xb0'` do you? You want to replace the *character*, not the sequence of 4 characters. `.replace('\xb0', r'\260')` would have been more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean

```
>>> test.encode('unicode-escape').replace(r'\xb0', r'\260')
'\\260C'
```

or

```
>>> ''.join('\\%o' % ord(c) for c in test)
'\\260\\103'
```

or most generous approach (that turns out to be in fact requested by OP)

```
>>> table = {i: unicode(chr(i)) if 32 <= i < 128 else u'\\%o' % i for i in range(256)}
>>> u'\xb0ABD\260'.translate(table)
u'\\260ABD\\260'
```

Comment: one more question, How can I avoid the double backslash (\\)? I want to get only one ;)

Comment: What do you mean by _remove backslash_? `\\260C` is merely a representation of a string `r'\260C'`; strings `\260C` and `\xb0C` equals: `'\260C' == '\xb0C'` outputs `True`

Comment: My problem is these result here: m/s\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\262 because I check "all" possible variants: e.g. text = text.encode('unicode-escape').replace(r'xb0', r'260') text = text.encode('unicode-escape').replace(r'\xb2', r'\262') and so on, with each call will be added new backslash. I think my solution is bad.

Comment: You could have done without the unicode escaping. `.replace('\xb0', r'\260')` would have done just fine.

Comment: @user2973395: What, `u'\xb0'.encode('latin1').replace('\xb0', r'\260')` works fine for me. Can you give us a test case instead? Sample input with expected output.

Comment: @user2973395 i added third snippet to handle more cases, see update

Comment: you're right MartijnPieters, my fault ;) because I took '\xb0' string without u. I think it's to late for me. But Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MartijnPieters with this string u'm/s\xb2' it doesn't work. alko: Thanks, i will try it.

Comment: @user2973395: That's because that is a different codepoint. If you need to handle different codepoints, then you'd need to use `translate()` or a regular expression. Moreover, you've underspecified your question then.

Comment: @alko: which is why I mentioned it. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters hmmm,It sounds a little bit complicated.

Comment: @user2973395: There is no silver bullet here. If you need to replace certain bytes with a non-standard encoding using octal escapes, you need to do so with the right tools. The answer here provides you with such a tool.

Comment: @alko Your example throws exception ;) or I do something wrong. >>> table = {i: unicode(chr(i)) if 32 <= i < 128 else u'\\%o' % i for i in range(256)}
  File "<interactive input>", line 1
    table = {i: unicode(chr(i)) if 32 <= i < 128 else u'\\%o' % i for i in range(256)}
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension

Comment: Ok, thanks. It rewrite the snippet for people like me ;)  _table = {}
    for i in range(256):
        if 32 <= i < 128:
            _table[i] = unicode(chr(i))
        else:
            _table[i] = u'\\%o' % i
    print u'\xb0ABD\260'.translate(_table)