# Dictionary Comprehension in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found the following stack overflow post about dict comprehensions in `Python2.7` and `Python 3+`: [Create a dictionary with list comprehension in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension) stating that I can apply dictionary comprehensions like this:

```
d = {key: value for (key, value) in sequence}
```

I tried it in Python 3. However, it raises an exception.

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
{key : value for (key, value) in d}
{key : value for key, value in d}
```

Both versions raise a `ValueError` saying that `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`.

**What is the easiest / the most direct way to make a dictionary comprehension in Python3?**

Comment: That dict comprehension expects a sequence of key-value pairs. You are feeding it a dict, which is not a sequence of key-value pairs.

Comment: I know that this is an old question, but I just wanted to add that to avoid the error, `d` should be `(('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3'), ('d', 4))`

Comment: You may refer this [Python Dictionary Comprehension](https://pythonexamples.org/python-dictionary-comprehension/) examples for how to use dictionary comprehension to create new dictionaries

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Looping over a dictionary only yields the **keys**. Use `d.items()` to loop over both keys and values:

```
{key: value for key, value in d.items()}
```

The `ValueError` exception you see is *not* a dict comprehension problem, nor is it limited to Python 3; you'd see the same problem in Python 2 or with a regular `for` loop:

```
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
>>> for key, value in d:
...     print key, value
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

because each iteration there is only *one* item being yielded.

Without a transformation, `{k: v for k, v in d.items()}` is just a verbose and costly `d.copy()`; use a dict comprehension only when you do a little more with the keys or values, or use conditions or a more complex loop construct.

Answer (score 12):

Well said above - you can drop items in Python3 if you do it this way:

> {key: d[key] for key in d}

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
z = {x: d[x] for x in d}
z
>>>{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

and this provides for the ability to use conditions as well

```
y = {x: d[x] for x in d if d[x] > 1}
y
>>>{'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary comprehension means generating items in the dictionary by some logic:

```
x = {p: p*p for p in range(10)}

print(x)

y = {q: q*3 for q in range(5,15) if q%2!=0}

print(y)
```