# Dictionary creation from sorted list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

This question is about nested dictionary comprehension and I have referred the [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489609/dictionary-comprehension-in-python-3) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915117/nested-dictionary-comprehension-python) before asking this.
I have a list whose first element is None and the remaining of it is a list of sorted positive numbers.

```
sorted_ar = [None, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 15, 25]
```

My requirement is to build a dictionary as:

```
key_dict = {10: [3, 2], 12: [12, 3], 15: [6, 1], 25: [7, 1]}
```

The values of the dictionary are a two element list, first element is the sum of indexes of the occurrences of key, second is the number of occurrences.
For example for element 12,
sum of indexes = 3+4+5 = 12 and number of occurrences is 3.
The following code does it.

```
 key_dict = {k:[0,0] for k in sorted_ar if k!=None}
        for i in range(len(sorted_ar)):
            if sorted_ar[i]:
                key_dict[sorted_ar[i]][0] += i
                key_dict[sorted_ar[i]][1] += 1
```

My requirement is to prepare the key_dict dictionary using dictionary comprehension.

My attempt:

```
key_dict = { 
    sorted_ar[i]:[ key_dict[sorted_ar[i]][0] + i,key_dict[sorted_ar[i]][0] + 1] 
    for i in range(1,len(sorted_ar)) if sorted_ar[i]!=None
}
```

But this is giving some erroneous result as

```
key_dict = {10: [2, 1], 12: [5, 1], 15: [6, 1], 25: [7, 1]}
```

How should I write the dictionary comprehension in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
sorted_ar = [None,10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 15, 25]

track={}
for i,j in enumerate(sorted_ar):
    if j not in track:
        track[j]=[(i,1)]
    else:
        track[j].append((i,1))


final_={}
for i,j in track.items():
    if i not in final_:
        final_[i]=(sum(list(map(lambda x:x[0],j))),sum(list(map(lambda x:x[1],j))))

print(final_)
```

output:

```
{None: (0, 1), 10: (3, 2), 15: (6, 1), 12: (12, 3), 25: (7, 1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use sorting, then look at [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#enumerate) to add indices:

```
from itertools import groupby

filtered = ((i, v) for i, v in enumerate(sorted_ar) if v)
grouped = ((v, list(g)) for v, g in groupby(filtered, lambda iv: iv[1]))
result = {v: [sum(i for i, v in g), len(g)] for v, g in grouped}
```

You can put this all into a single expression if you so desire:

```
result = {v: [sum(i for i, v in g), len(g)] for v, g in (
    (v, list(g)) for v, g in groupby((
        (i, v) for i, v in enumerate(sorted_ar) if v), lambda iv: iv[1]))}
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> sorted_ar = [None, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 15, 25]
>>> filtered = ((i, v) for i, v in enumerate(sorted_ar) if v)
>>> grouped = ((v, list(g)) for v, g in groupby(filtered, lambda iv: iv[1]))
>>> {v: [sum(i for i, v in g), len(g)] for v, g in grouped}
{10: [3, 2], 12: [12, 3], 15: [6, 1], 25: [7, 1]}
```

or as one long expression:

```
>>> {v: [sum(i for i, v in g), len(g)] for v, g in ((v, list(g)) for v, g in groupby(((i, v) for i, v in enumerate(sorted_ar) if v), lambda iv: iv[1]))}
{10: [3, 2], 12: [12, 3], 15: [6, 1], 25: [7, 1]}
```

Your dictionary approach, on the other hand, does not require the input to be sorted, so can be run in O(N) time (sorting takes O(NlogN) time).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sorted_ar = [None, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 15, 25] 
new_data = {i:[sum(c for c, b in enumerate(sorted_ar) if b == i), sorted_ar.count(i)] for i in sorted_ar if i}
```

Output:

```
{25: [7, 1], 10: [3, 2], 12: [12, 3], 15: [6, 1]}
```

Comment: Both the solutions are correct, however there is a reason I tried the way I tried. If you look at the for loop code that works ( 3rd snippet) , it looks simple/readable and has no comparison operations, the values are updated as and when a key is found.  I am looking for such a solution that has no comparison and written with basic python akin to the for loop solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found a way to achieve my behavior, not sure why, but the trick is that dictionary updates need to happen outside the comprehension.

```
def my_summer(i,num,key_dict):
    key_dict[num][0] = key_dict[num][0]+i
    return key_dict[num][0]  


def my_counter(num,key_dict):
    key_dict[num][1] +=1
    return key_dict[num][1]

sorted_ar = [None, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 15, 25] 
key_dict = {k:[0,0] for k in sorted_ar if k!=None}

key_dict = {sorted_ar[i]:[my_summer(i,sorted_ar[i],key_dict),my_counter(sorted_ar[i],key_dict)] for i in range(1,len(sorted_ar))}
```

Output: `{10: [3, 2], 12: [12, 3], 15: [6, 1], 25: [7, 1]}`