# What is wrong with my code which deals with creating python dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am learning python, and studying the dictionary concept.
Trying to make a new dictionary with key and values but not able to understand why is it giving error...

```
adict = {}

{
“a” : “apple”
“b” : “balloon”
}

print(adict)
```

Comment: missing a comma

Comment: What error are you getting? Is the problem the non-ASCII quotes you are using here?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Please ignore the quotes, I typed the question with phone pad, and not computer, but I was practising on computer and hence had used correct quotes..

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you would correctly initialize a dictionary with your given keys.

```
adict = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'balloon'}
```

Here is how you would initialize an empty dictionary.

```
adict = {}
```

The code you have just produces an invalid syntax error. It's unclear from your post which one you want. Also, good to note that you can also use, double quotes `"` or single quotes `'`. As one of the comments pointed out, your non-ascii quotes could also cause an error.

```
adict = {"a": "apple", "b": "balloon"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, some syntax errors,
try:

```
adict = {
"a" : "apple",
"b": "balloon"
}
print(adict)
```

Note the commas, and also the single pair of curly braces.

Secondly, where did you get those quotes? Did you copy and paste them from some place like a website or pdf? They are non-ascii so python won't understand them. Try typing them yourself. Thanks to chepner for pointing that out in the comments.

Answer (score -2):

The following code would work.

```
adict = {}

adict["a"] = "apple"
adict["b"] = "baloon"

print(adict)
```

Comment: I think this is being downvoted because it isn’t the simplest way to do this. It’s easier for a small dictionary like this to write it as shown in the other answers.

Answer (score -2):

In the first line, you created an empty dictionary and assigned it to “adict”.

You need to separate each key-value pair with commas and make sure that your keys do not have quotation Mars. Only the values have quotation marks (if they are strings).

```
adict = {
    “a”: “apple”, 
    “b”: “balloon”
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it will execute?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489609/dictionary-comprehension-in-python-3