# using dictionary comprehension for a new dict

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Been informed this has been answered - apoligies
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dictionary Comprehension in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489609/dictionary-comprehension-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

Since you wanted a function to perform this:

```
def newprice(d):
  return {"all" + key: value * 5 for key, value in d.items()}

# To be used as :

dict1 = {'apple':5, 'banana':4}
print(newprice(dict1))
```

Answer (score 0):

In dictionary comprehension you can do whatever you want to keys and values:

```py
def newprice(d):
  return {f'all{k}': v * 5 for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go  -

```
dict1 = {'apple':5, 'banana':4} 
dict2 = {('all'+ k): 5*dict1[k] for k in dict1 }
print(dict2)
```