# Python 3 sort a dict by its values

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

The only methods I found work for python2 or return only list of tuples.

Is it possible to sort dictionary, e.g. `{"aa": 3, "bb": 4, "cc": 2, "dd": 1}`, by its values?

Order of sorted dictionary I want to achieve is from largest to smallest. I want results to look like this:

```
bb 4
aa 3
cc 2
dd 1
```

And after sorting I want to store it into a text file.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`itemgetter` (see other answers) is (as I know) more efficient for large dictionaries but for the common case, I believe that `d.get` wins. And it does not require an extra `import`.

```
>>> d = {"aa": 3, "bb": 4, "cc": 2, "dd": 1}
>>> for k in sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True):
...     k, d[k]
...
('bb', 4)
('aa', 3)
('cc', 2)
('dd', 1)
```

Note that alternatively you can set `d.__getitem__` as `key` function which may provide a small performance boost over `d.get`.

Comment: Could you please explain|expand the syntax in line 2? I'm just learning Python 3 and would love to understand this one.

Comment: Sure but it would be easier if I would know what you do not understand. `[x for x in iterable]` is a Python List Comprehension (google) which is  very common and efficient in Python to create lists. `(k, d[k])` is a two element tuple, the second element (`d[k]`) is the value from the dictionary. `sorted()` is a builtin function returning the keys of the dictionary sorted by the values. Using `key=d.get` it the key of my answer which is not trivial to know. Knowing builtin functions is essential. I hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you! The `[x for x in iterable]` "List comprehension" is what was missing in the intro course. Now reading about it (was hard to find not knowing the name).

Comment: I made the code more simple with last edit which eliminiated the list comprehension entirely.

Answer (score 33):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter    

d = {"aa": 3, "bb": 4, "cc": 2, "dd": 1}
print(OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True)))
```

prints

```
OrderedDict([('bb', 4), ('aa', 3), ('cc', 2), ('dd', 1)])
```

Though from your last sentence, it appears that a list of tuples would work just fine, e.g.

```
from operator import itemgetter  

d = {"aa": 3, "bb": 4, "cc": 2, "dd": 1}
for key, value in sorted(d.items(), key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True):
    print(key, value)
```

which prints

```
bb 4
aa 3
cc 2
dd 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought that one of the solutions will be something similar to this.

Comment: `dict` keeps insertion order now, so there's no reason to use `OrderedDict`

Comment: I can think of two reasons, firstly it makes it explicit that you care about order, secondly someone may run your code on an older interpreter amd having it silently misbehave is not a good outcome.

Answer (score 26):

You can sort by **values** in **reverse** order (largest to smallest) using a [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python):

```
{k: d[k] for k in sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)}
# {'b': 4, 'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 1}
```

If you want to sort by **values** in ascending order (smallest to largest)

```
{k: d[k] for k in sorted(d, key=d.get)}
# {'d': 1, 'c': 2, 'a': 3, 'b': 4}
```

If you want to sort by the **keys** in ascending order

```
{k: d[k] for k in sorted(d)}
# {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'd': 1}
```

This works on CPython 3.6+ and any implementation of Python 3.7+ because dictionaries keep insertion order.

Answer (score 18):

Another way is to use a lambda expression. Depending on interpreter version and whether you wish to create a sorted dictionary or sorted key-value tuples (as the OP does), this may even be faster than the accepted answer.

```
d = {'aa': 3, 'bb': 4, 'cc': 2, 'dd': 1}
s = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for k, v in s:
    print(k, v)
```

Comment: While your code works, I don't think dictionaries are guaranteed to return the items in the same order as added.

Comment: @Ivan Thanks – I've removed the superfluous use of dict() here, although in CPython 3.6+, dict is order-preserving, and this is likely to become a language feature in the near future (https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html)

Comment: Thanks, it's interesting to know. Also - at the end you can just do `print(s)` instead of a loop :)

Comment: @Ivan Of course, but then the code wouldn't produce the output OP has requested…

Comment: `dict`s preserve order in all Pythons starting with 3.7

Comment: Your timings are unfair because for your method you're (presumably) timing returning a list of `(key, value)` tuples. If you time returning a dict from both methods: `%timeit {k: d[k] for k in sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)}` vs `%timeit dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))`, then *your* method is 10% slower.

Comment: actually it's less than 10%, I get 54 ms vs 57.3 ms on Python 3.8.6 with a 100,000 element dictionary, but still technically slower. I think you should remove them, it's not a worthwhile optimization.

Comment: @Boris Whether we benchmark reaching a sorted dict or a list of tuples is a matter of interpretation of the OP's question and their desired output: He says "I want results to look like this". However, it appears that as of CPython 3.8, either approach is slower using a lambda expression anyway, and as such I've removed speed claims and timings from my answer.

Answer (score 10):

To sort dictionary, we could make use of operator module. [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) is the operator module documentation.

```
import operator                             #Importing operator module
dc =  {"aa": 3, "bb": 4, "cc": 2, "dd": 1}  #Dictionary to be sorted

dc_sort = sorted(dc.items(),key = operator.itemgetter(1),reverse = True)
print dc_sort
```

Output sequence will be a sorted list :

```
[('bb', 4), ('aa', 3), ('cc', 2), ('dd', 1)]
```

If we want to sort with respect to keys, we can make use of

```
dc_sort = sorted(dc.items(),key = operator.itemgetter(0),reverse = True)
```

Output sequence will be :

```
[('dd', 1), ('cc', 2), ('bb', 4), ('aa', 3)]
```

Comment: The answer from Paul Draper is already using Operator...just not importing the complete library

Answer (score 0):

To sort a dictionary and keep it functioning as a dictionary afterwards, you could use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from the standard library.

If that's not what you need, then I encourage you to reconsider the sort functions that leave you with a list of tuples.  What output did you want, if not an ordered list of key-value pairs (tuples)?

Comment: `dict` keeps insertion order now, so there's no reason to use `OrderedDict`