# Given key value pairs, sort output alphabetically and increment values

Tags: python

```
dict1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 8, 'c':5} 
dict2 = {'d': 6, 'c': 4, 'a':20}
```

Given two dictionaries, I'd like an output of.

```
output = {'a':30, 'b':8, 'c':9, 'd':6}
```

This is what I've so far, not quite sure what I'd do next.
I'm looking for a solution that is efficient in time/space complexity.

```
def merge_dict(dict1, dict2):
    merged_dictionaries = {**dict1, **dict2} 
    return merged_dictionaries



dict1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 8, 'c':5} 
dict2 = {'d': 6, 'c': 4, 'a':20}


merge_dictionaries = merge_dict (dict1, dict2)
sorted_dictionary = sorted(merge_dictionaries)
```

Comment: why are you merging the dictionaries? Value will be lost for the same key.

Answer (score 3):

If the values are numeric, you can use counters:

```
from collections import Counter

def merge_dicts(*dicts):
    return dict(sum(map(Counter, dicts), Counter()))


dict1 = merge_dicts(dict1, dict2)
dict1

# {'a': 30, 'b': 8, 'c': 9, 'd': 6}
```

This might be a bit excessive for only two dictionaries, so another option is:

```
for k, v in dict2.items():
    dict1[k] = dict1.setdefault(k, 0) + v

dict1
# {'a': 30, 'b': 8, 'c': 9, 'd': 6}
```

Which updates `dict1` in-place.

Finally, if you really need the result sorted (python3.7+), use

```
result = {k : dict1[k] for k in sorted(dict1)}
```

Comment: These do not sort the output keys as the OP desires, however.

Comment: @blhsing I didn't think it was a very important requirement to fulfil, but I've edited nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict comprehension that iterates over a sorted union of the keys of the two dicts, and outputs values that are sums of the respective values of two dicts by the given keys, defaulting to 0:

```
{k: dict1.get(k, 0) + dict2.get(k, 0) for k in sorted(dict1.keys() | dict2.keys())}
```

This returns:

```
{'a': 30, 'b': 8, 'c': 9, 'd': 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = dict(Counter(dict1) + Counter(dict2))
result = {k: result[k] for k in sorted(result)}
```

First merge the dicts together by turning them into [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)s and convert the result it back into a `dict`, then [sort the dict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55292813/3064538) by keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try Collections for add two dictionary..

```
from collections import Counter
def merged_dic():
    dict1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 8, 'c':5} 
    dict2 = {'d': 6, 'c': 4, 'a':20}
    a = Counter(dict1)
    b = Counter(dict2)
    c = a+b
    print(dict(c))

merged_dic()
```

Output:- {'a': 30, 'b': 8, 'c': 9, 'd': 6}