# find the element with the highest value in the list of keys

Tags: python-3.x, max

Please, I am told to [find the maximum value of the list of keys in python](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud1110/lessons/c06382b2-cb27-4aac-a2bd-eb754fd13914/concepts/e72a31a5-b60a-42d6-abae-2b9471faebb5) but before that I was told to "create and sort a list of the dictionary's keys" and I did it with this code

```
sorted_keys = sorted(verse_dict.items(), key = lambda t: t[0])
```

But now, I am told to find the element with the highest value in the list of keys that I created.

[image: picture here]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3 sort a dict by its values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944483/python-3-sort-a-dict-by-its-values)

Answer (score 2):

Changing the indexing to `t[1]` (value) from `t[0]` (key) should work for your case:

```
sorted(verse_dict.items(), key = lambda t: t[1])
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate

Comment: No problem, glad it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you have sorted your dictionary according to the `key`, now if you want to sort it by `value`, you can sort it like this

```
sorted(verse_dict.items(), key = lambda t: t[1])
```

Just like how **Paul Lo** mentioned it.

But now, since you are supposed to find the key having highest value, what you need to do is access the last element using indexing, you can update the above code like this:

```
sorted(verse_dict.items(), key = lambda t: t[1])[-1][0]
```

And, you'll get the highest value containing key in your dictionary.

Hope it helps, thanks.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate

Answer (score -2):

Simply, get the last value of the sorted keys:

```
sorted_keys = sorted(verse_dict.keys())
sorted_keys[-1]
```