# AWS Lambda for cost explorer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm a new learner for AWS Lambda.

I'm trying to get data from AWS Cost Explorer and send a slack daily.

The data should be descending order but it's not.
Can you please give some tips for my code?

AWS Lambda seems not to allow to use `.getValue()` for sort function.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('ce')
    
    #get cost for each service daily
    serviceCost = get_daily_serviceCost(client)
        
    (title, detail) = create_message(totalCost, serviceCost)
    
    #transfer message to slack
    post_slack(title, detail)
    


def get_daily_serviceCost(client) -> list:
    
   
    today = datetime.date.today()
    yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    
  
    price = client.get_cost_and_usage(
        TimePeriod={
            'Start':datetime.date.strftime(yesterday, '%Y-%m-%d'),
            'End':datetime.date.strftime(today, '%Y-%m-%d')
        },
        Granularity='DAILY',
        Metrics=['BlendedCost'],
        GroupBy=[
            {
                'Type':'DIMENSION',
                'Key':'SERVICE'
            }
        ]
    )
    
    billings = []
    for item in price['ResultsByTime'][0]['Groups']:
        billings.append({
            'service_name':item['Keys'][0],
            'billing':item['Metrics']['BlendedCost']['Amount']
        })
    return billings
    

def create_message(serviceCost:list) -> (str):
    
    
    yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
   
    details = []         

    for item in serviceCost:
        service_name = item['service_name']
        billing = round(float(item['billing']),2)
        if billing == 0.00:
            continue
        details.append({service_name, billing})
       
    for check in details:
        print(check)
  
    test = []
    for what in serviceCost:
        test.append({service_name, billing})
        # print(what)
    test.sort(key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: AWS Lambda is just a virtual computing environment. It does not impact Python code in any way. Therefore, your issue is with correctly using Python on your `test` object, with nothing to do with AWS Lambda. Please edit your question and show us the contents of `test` both before and after calling `test.sort()`.

Comment: In the code there is no `getValue`. So its not clear what are you referring to?

Comment: So your question is around your last line of code, and you want to do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944483/python-3-sort-a-dict-by-its-values