# Having problems in extracting duplicates

Tags: python, duplicates, maya

I am stumped with this problem, and no matter how I get around it, it is still giving me the same result.

Basically, supposedly I have 2 groups - GrpA_null and GrpB_null, each having 2 meshes in them and are named exactly the same, brick_geo and bars_geo
- Result: GrpA_null --> brick_geo, bars_geo

But for some reason, in the code below which I presume is the one giving me problems, when it is run, the program states that GrpA_null has the same duplicates as GrpB_null, probably they are referencing the brick_geo and bars_geo. As soon as the code is run, my children geo have a numerical value behind, 
- Result: GrpA_null --> brick_geo0, bars_geo0, GrpB_null1 --> brick_geo, bars_geo1

And so, I tried to modify the code such that it will as long as the Parent (GrpA_null and GrpB_null) is different, it shall not 'touch' on the children.

Could someone kindly advice me on it?

```
    def extractDuplicateBoxList(self, inputs):
    result = {}

    for i in range(0, len(inputs)):
        print '<<< i is : %s' %i
        for n in range(0, len(inputs)):
            print '<<< n is %s' %n
            if i != n:
                name = inputs[i].getShortName()
                # Result: brick_geo

                Lname = inputs[i].getLongName()
                # Result: |GrpA_null|concrete_geo

                if name == inputs[n].getShortName():
                    # If list already created as result.
                    if result.has_key(name):
                        # Make sure its not already in the list and add it.
                        alreadyAdded = False
                        for box in result[name]:
                            if box == inputs[i]:
                                alreadyAdded = True
                        if alreadyAdded == False:
                            result[name].append(inputs[i])
                    # Otherwise create a new list and add it.
                    else:
                        result[name] = []
                        result[name].append(inputs[i])

    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you may want to be aware of.  First and foremost, indentation matters in Python.  I don't know if the indentation of your code as is is as intended, but your function code should be indented further in than your function def.

Secondly, I find your question a little difficult to understand.  But there are several things which would improve your code.

In the collections module, there is (or should be) a type called defaultdict.  This type is similar to a dict, except for it having a default value of the type you specify.  So a defaultdict(int) will have a default of 0 when you get a key, even if the key wasn't there before.  This allows the implementation of counters, such as to find duplicates without sorting.

```
from collections import defaultdict

counter = defaultdict(int)

for item in items:
    counter[item] += 1
```

This brings me to another point. Python for loops implement a for-each structure.  You almost never need to enumerate your items in order to then access them.  So, instead of

```
for i in range(0,len(inputs)):
```

you want to use

```
for input in inputs:
```

and if you really need to enumerate your inputs

```
for i,input in enumerate(inputs):
```

Finally, you can iterate and filter through iterable objects using list comprehensions, dict comprehensions, or generator expressions.  They are very powerful.  See [Create a dictionary with list comprehension in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension)

Try this code out, play with it.  See if it works for you.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def extractDuplicateBoxList(self, inputs):
    counts = defaultdict(int)

    for input in inputs:
        counts[input.getShortName()] += 1
    dup_shns = set([k for k,v in counts.items() if v > 1])
    dups = [i for i in inputs if input.getShortName() in dup_shns]

    return dups
```

Comment: @bitslpit Thanks for getting back to me and I sincerely apologize regarding the indentation, after much copying and pasting, I must have forgotten to recheck it again. I will try and test to see if the codes will work in mine, however could you please elaborate your code from dup_shns onwards? While I can somewhat make sense of it, but I do not understand the relation of k and v...

Comment: Sure thing.  for a dict type, items returns a list (or iterator in py3k) of key value pairs. [k for k,v in counts.items()] would be a list of all keys in counts.items(). [k for k,v in counts.items() if v > 1] is a list of all keys in counts.items() where the value is greater than 1.  This would be a list of all short names that are duplicated.  passing it to set makes the list a set, which is more efficient for checking if an item is or is not in the container.  Finally [i for i in inputs if...] would return the inputs that match the short name in the set of duplicated short names.

Comment: @bitslpit Thanks for getting back to me and I think I kinda get what you mean. Probably needs to read up more on my own to further my understanding. Even so, it seems that I may be wrong in determining the code as I have just tried the solution provided by you and eyquem, it does not seems to be working at all.

Comment: You may want to watch this video by Raymond Hettinger on youtube. http://youtu.be/OSGv2VnC0go

Answer (score 0):

I was on the point to write the same remarks as ***bitsplit***, he has already done it.

So I just give you for the moment a code that I think is doing exactly the same as yours, based on these remarks and the use of the `get` dictionary's method:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def extract_Duplicate_BoxList(self, inputs):
    result = defaultdict()

    for i,A in enumerate(inputs):
        print '<<< i is : %s' %i
        name  = A.getShortName() # Result: brick_geo
        Lname = A.getLongName()  # Result: |GrpA_null|concrete_geo

        for n in (j for j,B in enumerate(inputs)
                  if j!=i and B.getShortName()==name):
            print '<<< n is %s' %n
            if A not in result.get(name,[])):
                result[name].append(A)

    return result
```

.

Secondly, as ***bitsplit*** said it, I find your question ununderstandable.
Could you give more information on the elements of inputs ?
Your explanations about GrpA_null and GrpB_null and the names and the meshes are unclear.

.

EDIT:
If my reduction/simplification is correct, examining it , I see that What you essentially does is to compare `A` and `B` elements of `inputs` (with `A!=B`) and you record `A` in the dictionary `result` at key `shortname` (only one time) if `A` and `B` have the same shortname `shortname`;
I think this code can still be reduced to just:

```
def extract_Duplicate_BoxList(inputs):
    result = defaultdict()

    for i,A in enumerate(inputs):
        print '<<< i is : %s' %i
        result[B.getShortName()].append(A)

    return result
```

Comment: Both GrpA_null and GrpB_null contains 2 meshes, namely brick_geo and bars_geo in them. Meaning to say there are 2 meshes in each group but of the same naming. Apparently for my coding, whenever I run it, it seems to be stating that there are duplication in it (due to the meshes of the same naming) and it adds on a numerical factor in the 4 meshes such as brick_geo0, bars_geo0 for GrpA_null and brick_geo1, bars_geo1 for GrpB_null...

Answer (score 0):

this may be do what your looking for if I understand it, which seems to be comparing the sub-hierarchies of different nodes to see if they are they have the same names.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def child_nodes(node):
    ''' returns a set with the relative paths of all <node>'s children'''
    root = cmds.ls(node, l=True)[0]
    children = cmds.listRelatives(node, ad=True, f=True)
    return set( [k[len(root):] for k in children])

child_nodes('group1')
# Result: set([u'|pCube1|pCubeShape1', u'|pSphere1', u'|pSphere1|pSphereShape1', u'|pCube1']) # 

# note the returns are NOT valid maya paths, since i've removed the root <node>, 
# you'd need to add it back in to actually access a real shape here:

all_kids = child_nodes('group1')
real_children  = ['group1' + n for n in all_kids ]
```

Since the returns are sets, you can test to see if they are equal,  see if one is a subset or superset of the other, see what they have in common and so on:

```
# compare children
child_nodes('group1') == child_nodes('group2')

#one is subset:
child_nodes('group1').issuperset(child_nodes('group2'))
```

Iterating over a bunch of nodes is easy:

```
# collect all the child sets of a bunch of nodes:
kids =   dict ( (k, child_nodes(k)) for k in ls(*nodes))
```