# Syntax error when trying to import folium

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-import

This seems like a really simple issue.  I installed folium just fine but I get a syntax error in my program on the import statement.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python_scripts/interactivemap.py", line 3, in <module>
    import folium as f
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/folium/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from folium.folium import Map, initialize_notebook
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/folium/folium.py", line 23, in <module>
    from folium import utilities
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/folium/utilities.py", line 235
    json_data = [{type_check(x): type_check(y) for x, y in iteritems(data)}]
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm really lost as to what could be causing this except maybe the fact that I'm running python 2.6 but I didn't see anything indicating an issue like this.

Comment: You cant use dict comprehension with python 2.6.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension

Comment: Use python2.7, dont use 2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Python 2.6, you'll need to manually create the dictionary:

```
d = dict()

for k,v in iteritems(data):  # Not sure where you got
                             # this method from
    d[type_check(k)] = type_check(v)

json_data = [d] # or import simplejson as json; json_data = json.dumps(d)
```