# Porting to an older version; syntax issues

Tags: python

I wrote a project in 2.7.9 and now have to port it to 2.4.3. I have a one-liner that is giving me syntax issues and am not sure what part of it does not comform to 2.4.3.

Code:

```
file = open(fileName, 'r')
header = [a for a in file.readline().split(',')]
data = [{x : y for x, y in zip(header, line.strip('\n').split(','))} for line in file]
```

Error: =

```
data = [{x : y for x, y in zip(header, line.strip('\n').split(','))} for line in file]
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1747827/3001761

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were no dictionary comprehensions in Python 2.4. They got introduced in Python 2.7.

You can rewrite

```
{x : y for x, y in zip(header, line.strip('\n').split(','))}
```

as

```
dict(zip(header, line.strip('\n').split(',')))
```