# Put maximum of each column from a list of dataframe into new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I recently started working with pandas dataframes.

I have a list of dataframes called 'arr'.

Edit: All the dataframes in 'arr' have same columns but different data. 
Also, I have an empty dataframe 'ndf' which I need to fill in using the above list.
How do I iterate through 'arr' to fill in the max values of a column from 'arr' into a row in 'ndf'
So, we'll have

> Number of rows in *ndf* = Number of elements in *arr*

I'm looking for something like this:

```
columns=['time','Open','High','Low','Close']
ndf=DataFrame(columns=columns)
ndf['High']=arr[i].max(axis=0)
```

Comment: Do all of your dataframes in the list have the same columns?

Comment: Could you please give a small example of what data you have and what you want in the end?

Comment: did your code give a result? an error?

Comment: @James, Yes the all the dataframes in the list have same columns with different data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I assume a basic example of your data looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data =[{'time':'2013-09-01','open':249,'high':254,'low':249,'close':250},
       {'time':'2013-09-02','open':249,'high':256,'low':248,'close':250}]
data2 =[{'time':'2013-09-01','open':251,'high':253,'low':248,'close':250},
        {'time':'2013-09-02','open':245,'high':251,'low':243,'close':247}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
arr = [df, df2]
```

If that's the case, then you can simply iterate over the list of dataframes (via `enumerate()`) and the columns of each dataframe (via `iteritems()`, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#iteritems), populating each new row via a dictionary comprehension: (see [Create a dictionary with list comprehension in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension)):

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
for i, df in enumerate(arr):
    ndf = ndf.append(pd.DataFrame(data = {colName: max(colData) for colName, colData in df.iteritems()}, index = [i]))
```

If some of your dataframes have any additional columns, the resulting dataframe `ndf` will have `NaN` entries in the relevant places.