# Python dictionary function resulting in syntax error on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax

I have a line of code that creates a dictionary by setting its key as that of the key of dictionary_b. It then uses the value of that key in dictionary_b as the key to look through dictionary_a to grab the corresponding value.

```
new_dictionary = {key : dictionary_a.get(value, value) for key, value in dictionary_b.iteritems()}
```

This compiles fine on Windows however when I try to use compile on Linux I get the following error:

```
  File "IP_Merger.py", line 46
    new_ip = {key : dictionary_a.get(value, value) for key, value in dictionary_b.iteritems()}
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

On Windows I am compiling on Python 2.7 and on Linux 2.6.6. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionary comprehensions are supported starting in Python 2.7 - see [this quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension) for more information.

You can create a dictionary with a generator as follows in python 2.6:

```
dict((key(s),value(s)) for s in something)
```