# Populating dictionary from text file PYTHON

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I am trying to read in this text file.

```
A B C D
1 5 6 7
2 8 9 10
3 .......
4 .......
```

The letter are brought in as a line, then I just bring in all the values as floats as

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
  headings = f.readline()

  numbers = [float(n) for n in f.read().split()] #read values to the 'numbers' as a list 
  print numbers
```

So I have a long list of all the integers.

But I want the dictionary in this format:

```
my_dict( { 1: [5,6,7], 2:[8,9,10] } )
```

so the first column of files numbers are the keys, and the rest are a list correlating to their respective key.

I am setting up every 4th value as a key with a loop, but how can I easily get the rest of the values as a list into that respective key.

Comment: Not using the column headers?

Comment: @MattH It seems like the row and column headers are going to be both used.

Comment: You should consider accepting one of the answers provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily with the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and `dict` with a generator expression:

```
import csv

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    next(f) # skip header
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    d = dict((int(row[0]), map(int,row[1:])) for row in r)
    print(d)

{1: [5, 6, 7], 2: [8, 9, 10]}
```

If you have repeating keys then you will need another approach or you will lose data, a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) will handle repeats:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    d = defaultdict(list)
    r = csv.reader(f,delimiter=" ")
    for row in r:
       d[row[0]].extend(map(int,row[1:]))
```

If you want every four rows in its own dict you can use [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) on the csv.reader object:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    next(f) # skip header
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    out = []
    for row in iter(lambda: list(islice(r, 4)),[]):
        out.append(dict((int(r[0]), map(int,r[1:])) for r in row ))
```

Which for:

```
A B C D
1 5 6 7
2 8 9 10
5 5 6 7
6 8 9 10
1 2 3 4
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
```

Will output:

```
[{1: [5, 6, 7], 2: [8, 9, 10], 5: [5, 6, 7], 6: [8, 9, 10]}, {1: [2, 3, 4], 2: [2, 2, 2], 3: [3, 3, 3], 4: [4, 4, 4]}]
```

You can put it all inside a list comp:

```
 out = [dict((int(r[0]), map(int,r[1:])) for r in row) 
       for row in iter(lambda: list(islice(r, 4)),[])]
```

Comment: For your first method I changed the delimiter because its tabs not spaces in my file, works fine.  I do have repeating keys, every four lines the key will be repeated BUT I would like them in separate dictionaries because they can just be operated with as separate instances of a calculation class.

Comment: @cc6g11, then we just need to use itertools.islice. I will edit

Comment: @cc6g11, you want a list of dicts yes?

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham So what is the correct way to reference any key or any part of its respective list?

Comment: @cc6g11, `d[key]` will give you the list/value. If you want to get a certain item from the list use `d[key][index]`. What are you actually doing with the data? Also to access the list of dicts either iterate or index the list to get each dict then access as above. You can also store a list of lists for each key if you change extend to append in the defaultdict code

Answer (score 5):

```
mydict = {}
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    headings = f.readline()

    for row in f:
        row = row.split()
        key = row[0]
        vals = row[1:]
        mydict[key] = vals
```

Something like that? Or have i missunderstood your desired result?
Since you're not using the actual headers `A B C D ...` I'm not going to try and do something with them so i'll leave your solution for that as it is.

Also you've written some sort of class called `my_dict` (?) which I won't try to use because I have no idea what it actually is.

If you need the values to be integers along your output, simply do something like:

```
row = row.split()
row = list(int(n) for n in row)
```

Comment: Works perfect.  I'm new to python coming from C, can you explain WHY the for loop works the way it does? THANKS!

Comment: @cc6g11 sure, i'd love to. But you mean the `for row in f`? It indirectly calls `f.readline()` as a iterator object enabling you to work line by line on the file. you could also do `for row in f.readline()` :)

Answer (score 0):

Reading can be done with numpy [`loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt) or [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html). To create the dictionary, I'd prefer a [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension).
Note that I have used commas as separator for my sample file.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('filename.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1, dtype=np.float32)
mydict = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in data}

print mydict
>> {1.0: array([  5.,   6.,  12.], dtype=float32),
>> 2.0: array([  6.,   9.,  13.], dtype=float32),
>> 3.0: array([  7.,  10.,  14.], dtype=float32),
>> 4.0: array([  8.,  11.,  15.], dtype=float32)}
```

`dtypes` can, of course, be modified according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

`i = iter(numbers)
print [{r[0]: list(r[1:]) for r in zip(i,i,i,i)}]`

Answer (score 0):

Since you need it in float and if you want to know how to do it in a dictionary comprehension

> this answer is just a modification to Torexed's answer

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    headings = f.readline()
    mydict={float(row[0]):[float(i) for i in row[1:]] for row in (rows.split(',') for rows in f)}
    print mydict
```