# object storage in python that allow tuples as keys

Tags: python, dictionary, persistent-object-store

I am searching for an object storage in python that allows me to store a dictionary having `tuple`s as keys. I already tried [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) and [shove](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/shove/), which both exit with an error as soon as I pass my dictionary. Are there any solutions out that provide this?

For shove,

```
from shove import Shove
data = Shove('file://tmp')
("a",) in data
```

it gives me `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rstrip'`. But only, if the tuple is not in data.

```
from shove import Shove
data = Shove('file://tmp')
data[("a",)] = 2
("a",) in data
```

would not throw an error.

For shelve,

```
import shelve
d = shelve.open('tmp/test.db')
d[('a',)] = 2
```

gives me `TypeError: dbm mappings have string indices only`

Comment: have you tried pickle?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I would love to have the simplicity of accessing data just by `data[tuple(key1,key2)] = 3` as it is provided by shelve and shove. I thought with pickle, I can only load or save the whole dictionary

Comment: you could build a proxy class that just json-encodes the input (so it's a string) and passes that on to shelve/shove... then they would be guaranteed to be strings... assuming the tuples are simple (i.e. only composed of data that is json-encodable, not complex classes)...

Comment: @CorleyBrigman beat me to it. Are your `tuple`s convertible to a unique string representation? e.g., `tuple`s of `int`s should(?) have consistent and unique string representations, and the original `tuple` of `ints` can be retrieved with, e.g., `tuple(map(int,"(1,2,3)"[1:-1].split(',')))`.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman as my examples allude, I have tuples of strings, which make a conversion to a combined string error-prone - with correct escaping this *would be* a working solution, but is it a good one?

Comment: It's not error-prone... i posted an answer that demonstrates this, every tuple that is different should have a different (backwards-compatible) encoding... but it does involve processing on every lookup. I don't see any way around that really though (somewhere). I realized that you may get better performance with `repr` vs `json.dumps` though...initial tests show about an order of magnitude improvement there. i'll propose a solution below...

Comment: actually, what i was going to post is a simpler version of what you've already accepted... but in general, every picked tuple should be unique.

Comment: btw (way too many comments, sorry!) - repr is about 3x faster than pickle: `json.dumps((1,0))` = ~4.37uS, `pickle.dumps((1,0))` = ~1.42uS, `repr((1,0))` = ~511nS on my machine.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman what would you use as inverse of `repr`? wouldn't `eval` be a loss of generality?

Comment: it's not a loss of generality... `('1,0', '0')` is different from `('1', '0,0')`, and the `repr` versions are also different (they're exactly what i wrote above). that said. if you need to iterate keys a lot (which requires reversing them), `ast.literal_eval` (what i would use) is very slow (~15 uS, vs. ~1.5uS for cPickle). if you're only doing lookups, then you don't need to reverse. But I suppose pickle is far more general, and these times are probably going to be dwarfed by DB lookup for most cases (when it's not already in memory) anyways...

Comment: btw, a solution like @Brian's above is way faster than even cPickle (i used `tuple(int(x) for x in y[1:-1].split(','))` before i saw his, which is very close, and took 300nS). but i don't think a simple solution like that exists for arbitrary strings.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Seems like the primary constraint for using tuples of strings as keys would be that the strings must be guaranteed to never contain a comma. `str` rep of a `tuple` should always have enclosing parentheses (`key[1:-1]` seems like it should be universally reliable), and then a `split` on `,` should recover the tuple. *{tests it}* Doesn't work, actually -- `str({tuple of strings})` explicitly stores the quotes around each tuple element. Would take more finagling.

Comment: something like `[x[1:-1] for x in xs[1:-1].split(',')]` should work in that case. Not allowing commas in the strings might not be an onerous requirement - they could be identifiers, for instance - but it's certainly not general. (literal_eval or pickle both handle this already, of course, by either doing full syntax decoding (literal_eval) or storing an intermediate representation (pickle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shelve` is a module from Python Standard Library. The doc is clear about that : *the values (not the keys!) in a shelf can be essentially arbitrary Python objects — anything that the pickle module can handle ... The keys are ordinary strings*

By construction shelve will only accept strings as keys.

Shove is still in Beta according to the documentation from pypi, and I could not see any evidence that it supports anything other that a string for the key (the error `object has no attribute 'rstrip'` let think it does not).

If I were you, I would stick to the well known `shelve`, and just wrap it with a key serialisation layer. As suggested by Padraic Cunningham, `pickle` should do the job.

Here is a (not extensively tested) possible implementation :

```
class tuple_dict(collections.MutableMapping):
    class iterator(collections.Iterator):
        def __init__(self, d):
            self.it = d.udict.__iter__()
        def __iter__(self):
            return self
        def next(self):
            return pickle.loads(next(self.it))
    def __init__(self, udict):
        self.udict = udict
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        ukey = pickle.dumps(key)
        return self.udict[ukey]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        ukey = pickle.dumps(key)
        self.udict[ukey] = value
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        ukey = pickle.dumps(key)
        del self.udict[ukey]
    def keys(self):
        return [ pickle.loads(key) for key in self.udict.keys() ]
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.iterator(self)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.udict)
    def __contains__(self, key):
        return pickle.dumps(key) in self.udict
    def sync(self):
        self.udict.sync()
    def close(self):
        self.udict.close()
```

You would use it that way :

```
import shelve
underlying_d = shelve.open('tmp/test.db')
d = tuple_dict(underlying_d)
```

d will then accept tuple as keys and stores that all in the underlying shelf.

NB : if you later want to use a different persistence implementation, provided the implementation is a mapping (dict like class), you could reuse the `tuple_dict` by simply changing the close and sync methods (shelve specifice) but what would be needed by the other implentation. In fact apart from these 2 methods tuple_dict just wraps an ordinary dict - and as such any mapping class ...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how pythonic this is but... how about defining a constant separator string as something almost impossible to occur in your key strings:

```
sep = '#!#!#!#'
```

and then, when you need to create a key for `shelve` out of a tuple of strings, just `.join` them into a crude hash:

```
import shelve
d = shelve.open('tmp/test.db')
d[sep.join(('a',))] = 2
```

If you should need to regenerate a `tuple` key from information contained within the `shelve` repository, it's as easy as a `.split`:

```
my_dict = { tuple(k.split(sep)): d[k] for k in d.keys() }
```

*Per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension), this direct `dict` comprehension syntax is only supported for Python 2.7 and newer, but there are alternatives for 2.6 and earlier.*

In your case, since you already have a dictionary defined, you'd have to do some dict-fu to hot-swap your current `tuple` keys for the `str`-ified hash when interacting with the `shelve` repository, but this shouldn't be too hard.

This approach isn't completely bug-free, but arguably can be made such that the probability of problems arising from collisions of `sep` with your `tuple`-of-`str` keys is vanishingly small.  Also, note that this approach will only work if your keys are *strictly* `tuple`s of `str`s.