# Joining dictionaries in a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a simple for loop

```
    for m in my_list:
        x = my_function(m)
        my_dictionary = {m:x}
```

`my_function()` gives me a string. And if I use `print my_dictionary` at the end i get

```
   {m1: string1}
   {m2: string2}
```

I want to be able to have one dictionary at the end.
I have tried several methods that I found in other threads.
`dic = dict(my_dictionary, **my_dictionary)`

```
dic = my_dictionary.copy()
dic.update(my_dictionary)
```

But overtime I just get the last dictionary instead of all dictionaries.
I wish I could just add them with `+`, but you can't do that in python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [dict comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/python-create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension) to create your main dict:

```
dic = {m : my_function(m) for m in my_list}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating separate dictionaries in the first place? Just set the key in an existing dict on each iteration.

```
my_dictionary = {}
for m in my_list:
    x = my_function(m)
    my_dictionary[m] = x
```

Comment: Same here, was overthinking it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't your problem just that you want a simple, non-nested dictionary, and you keep overwriting it within the loop? In that case, this small change should suffice:

```
my_dictionary = {}
for m in my_list:
    x = my_function(m)
    my_dictionary[m] = x
```

Comment: I guess I was overthinking it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can update the dictionary as opposed to overwrite it each time.

```
my_dictionary = {}
for m in my_list:
    x = my_function(m)
    my_dictionary.update({m:x})
print my_dictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to recreate a new dictionnary at each loop iteration.

You can either create the dictionnary before and add items to it as you iterate:

```
my_dict = {}
for m in my_list:
    my_dict[m] = my_function(m)
```

or you can use a dict comprehension:

```
my_dict = {m:my_function(m) for m in my_list}
```

or, in python 2:

```
my_dict = dict((m,my_function(m)) for m in my_list)
```