# python 3 comprehension dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code:

```
def brujinGraph(k, strList):

    vertex = [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]]

    brujinGraph = {strList[i]: strList[j][:-1] for i in range(len(vertex)) for j in range(k) and vertex[i][j] == 1}

    return brujinGraph

strList = ['AAGA', 'AAGA', 'AGAT', 'ATTC', 'CTAA', 'CTCT', 'GATT', 'TAAG', 'TCTA', 'TCTC', 'TTCT']
brujinGraph(4, strList)
```

and it is throwing me an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'j' referenced before assignment`

any idea what does it means and why am I getting this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a dictionary with list comprehension in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python)

Comment: Please show us the rest of your code so we can reproduce it. To me it looks like your trying to reference a key `j` in `strList`(assuming `strList` is a dict) when j doesnt exist in `strList`.

Comment: The second range will be evaluated before the `for j`, and the range depends on `j`. That just won't work.

Comment: @Signal I put my code so you can reproduce

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I get same error even if I change the second range with a contant

Comment: Could you explain what your desired output is? There are multiple oddities in the comprehension so I can't quite figure out what needs to be changed to get the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what vertex and strList are :

Do you actually mean :

```
{strList[i]: strList[j][:-1] for i in range(len(vertex)) for j in range(len(vertex[i])) if vertex[i][j] == 1}
```

i.e. change that **and** into an **if**

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues:

1. You need an `if` not an `and` at the end
2. I think it is better expressed this way:

   `brujinGraph = {strList[i]: strList[j][:-1] for i, x in enumerate(vertex) for j, e in enumerate(x) if e == 1}`