# How to add to dictionary from input

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm just starting out at Python and need some help with dictionaries. I'm looking to add keys to a dictionary based on input that is a list with string elements:

Ex.

```
x = {}
a = ['1', 'line', '56_09', '..xxx..']
```

Now say a while loop has come to this list a. I try to add to the dictionary with this code:

```
if a[1] == 'line':
    x[a[2]] = [a[-1]]
```

I want the dictionary to read `x = { '56_09': '..xxx..'}` and want to confirm that by printing it. Do i need to adjust the elements on the list to strings or is it something with the if statement that I need to change?

Comment: a[1] is not 'line'. a['1'] is 'line'.

Comment: @Goodies, `a` is a list, not a dictionary

Comment: @Jrills, shouldn't it be `x[a[2]] = a[-1]`?

Answer (score 2):

The one problem with your code is in the `if` block:

```
if a[1] == 'line':
    x[a[2]] = [a[-1]]
```

Instead, it should be like this:

```
if a[1] == 'line':
    x[a[2]] = a[-1]
```

What you did was creating a list with one element: the last element of the list `a`.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a dict object form two lists using ZIP and dict()

dict(zip(list1,list2)).

I believe for your question make two list form the input list based on the requirement and use above syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this : -

```
def check(x,a):
    if 'line' in a[1]:
        x[a[2]] = a[-1]
        return x
```

After

```
check({},['1', 'line', '56_09', '..xxx..'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if a[1]=='line':
    x={a[2]:a[-1]}
```

dictionary comprehension [Create a dictionary with list comprehension in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python)

```
{r:"test" for r in range(10)}
```