# split string on commas but ignore commas with in single quotes and create a dictionary after string split in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.x

I  have a string as shown below,

```
someVariable1='9',someVariable2='some , value, comma,present',somevariable5='N/A',someVariable6='some text,comma,= present,'
```

I have to split above string on commas but ignore commas within quotes in python and i have to create a dictionary to get the values of variables.

Example:

```
somedictionary.get('someVariable1')
```

I am new to python please help me how can i achieve this in python

Comment: Are you new to programming in general, or just Python?

Comment: The string looks like you could split it with the csv parser and `'` as the `quotechar`.

Comment: hi john I am a java developer and new to python scripting language

Comment: I notice you have put the many version-specific python tags... is there a reason you put all these (as in you want a version-specific answer)?

Comment: @SethMMorton fixed that (partly). What exactly have you tried so far OP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regular expression `,(?=(?:[^']*\'[^']*\')*[^']*$)` for splitting:

```
import re
re.split(",(?=(?:[^']*\'[^']*\')*[^']*$)",s)

# ["someVariable1='9'",
#  "someVariable2='some , value, comma,present'",
#  "somevariable5='N/A'",
#  "someVariable6='some text,comma,= present,'"]
```

- This uses look ahead syntax `(?=...)` to find out specific comma to split;
- The look up pattern is `(?:[^']*\'[^']*\')*[^']*$`
- `$` matches the end of string and optionally matches non `'` characters `[^']*`
- Use non-captured group `(?:..)` to define a double quote pattern `[^']*\'[^']*\'` which could appear behind the comma that can acts as a delimiter.

This assumes the quotes are always paired.

To convert the above to a dictionary, you can split each sub expression by `=`:

```
lst = re.split(",(?=(?:[^']*\'[^']*\')*[^']*$)",s)
dict_ = {k: v for exp in lst for k, v in [re.split("=(?=\')", exp)]}

dict_

# {'someVariable1': "'9'",
#  'someVariable2': "'some , value, comma,present'",
#  'someVariable6': "'some text,comma,= present,'",
#  'somevariable5': "'N/A'"}

dict_.get('someVariable2')
# "'some , value, comma,present'"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Psidom,@John for the detailed explanation, It is working perfectly.

Comment: when i execute the same piece of code in python 2.4.6 i am getting below error ,                                                                               detailsdict = {k: v for exp in detailslist for k, v in [re.split("=(?=\')", exp)]}
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @sreekanthramagiri dictionary comprehensions were added in `Python 2.7` if I'm not mistaken. *Don't use `Python 2.4.6`*.

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python dict((k, v) for ...) should work for the old version.

Comment: How did you come up with this expression?  I don't think I will ever be able to come up with this expression.

Answer (score 0):

Build a copy of the string, looping through each character of the original string, and keeping track of the number of single-quotes you've encountered.

Whenever you see a comma, refer to the single-quote count.  If it's odd (meaning you're currently inside a quoted string), don't add the comma onto the string copy; instead add some unique placeholder value (i.e. something like  PEANUTBUTTER that would never actually appear in the string.)

When you're finished building the string copy, it won't have any commas inside quotes, because you replaced all those with PEANUTBUTTER, so you can safely split on commas.

Then, in the list you got from splitting, go back and replace PEANUTBUTTER with commas.