# python strange looking loop

Tags: python

```
      char_rdic = list('helo')
      char_dic = {w:i for i ,w in enumerate(char_rdic)}
```

I'm not really sure what this code actually do. what does w and i represent  in this code?

Comment: `w` are members of `char_rdic`, `i` will be index. `enumerate(iterable)` returns pairs of `index, iterable_member` as seen here https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: The strange looking loop is called a list comprehension, or dictionary comprehension in this case.

Comment: and `w:i` creates the `key-value` pair for the dictionary

Comment: oh thx for the term! how to check the value with dictionary?

Comment: In the future, check from the docs first: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: sorry i just did not know the term before

Answer (score 1):

This is a dict comprehension. If you are familiar with list comprehension (`[do_stuff(a) for a in iterable]` construct), that works very much the same way, but it builds a dict.

See [Create a dictionary with list comprehension in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python)
and https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries for the official documentation

Comment: thank you for comment. I do not understand people who keep giving negative things. my native language is not english. and i'm new to programming and also 12 years old. i'm trying to learn. but people are so mean.

Answer (score 0):

This code creates `char_dic` dictionary with chars from `'helo'` string as keys and their occurence indexes in given string.
`i` is an index of `w` element in `char_rdic` list.