# Multiple 'for' loops in dictionary generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

In [this Python documentation](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) the following is used as an example of a generator expression:

```
dict((fn(i+1), code)
    for i, code in enumerate('FGHJKMNQUVXZ')
    for fn in (int, str))

>> {1: 'F', '1': 'F', 2: 'G', '2': 'G', 3: 'H', '3': 'H', 4: 'J',...}
```

I don't understand how the second `for` loop, `for fn in (int, str)`, turns the int value into a string and adds an additional entry to the dictionary.

I have found [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python), but I still wasn't able to intuit how the second `for` loop works in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are constructing a dictionary using a sequence (here provided by a generator expression) of tuples expressed by the following literal

```
(fn(i+1), code)
```

In this tuple literal all the terms (except `1`:) are provided by the two loops; the outer loop

```
… for i, code in enumerate('TROIDSNB') …
```

provides you `i`, an integer value and `code`, a 1 character long string — these values are fixed when you execute the inner loop;
the inner loop provides you the value of `fn`

```
… for fn in (int, str) …
```

that can assume 2 values, either `fn=int` or `fn=str`.

When the first tuple is constructed, `i=0`, `code='T'` and `fn=int`

```
(int(0+1), 'T')
```

when the second tuple is constructed, `i` and `code` (provided by the *outer* loop) have not changed but `fn=str`, so the new tuple, passed to the dictionary constructor, is

```
(str(0+1), 'T')
```

At this point the inner loop has reached its end… the outer loop updates the values of its variables, `i=1` and `code=R`, the inner loop is reset, hence `fn=int` and a new tuple is generated

```
(int(1+1), 'R')
```

etc etc

Answer (score 8):

It may help to "unroll" the loops in the generator expression, and write them as independent `for` loops. To do so, you take all the `for (variable) in (iterable)` statements and put them on separate lines, in the same order, but move the thing from the front to the body of the innermost for loop. Like this, in general:

```
thing for a in a_list for b in b_list for c in c_list
```

becomes

```
for a in a_list:
    for b in b_list:
        for c in c_list:
            thing
```

except that when you do the generator expression, all the `thing`s automatically go into the list or dictionary or whatever. In your case,

```
dict((fn(i+1), code)
    for i, code in enumerate('FGHJKMNQUVXZ')
    for fn in (int, str))
```

becomes

```
for i, code in enumerate('FGHJKMNQUVXZ'):
    for fn in (int, str):
        (fn(i+1), code)
```

except that all the tuples will be converted into a `dict`.

As the other answers explain, you can trace the execution of these two `for` loops. First, the outer loop sets `i` to `0` and `code` to `'F'`, and within that, the inner loop sets `fn` to `int` and then to `str`, so you get

```
int(0+1, 'F')
str(0+1, 'F')
```

after which it goes on to the next `i` and `code`.

Comment: I like this way of explaining by code transformation! If it were me, I would maybe only use two levels in general intro to stay close to the question and also avoid `a_list` in favor of `a_seq` or `a_iterable` (list is so concrete) - but it is not me ;-)

Comment: @Dilettant I wanted to use a different number of levels to show how the technique generalizes. You're right that something like `a_iter` would probably be a better name, but I figured it's not too important because learners at this level are not too concerned with the differences between lists and iterables.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful feedback and I share the intent as generalizing is exactly what it is - I am often astonished what exactly hits the eye of a learner and what is derived from it - esp. when learning myself :-)

Answer (score 4):

As you can see `fn(i+1)` will be called two times. First `int(i+1)`, second `str(i+1)`

```
for a in ((fn(i+1), code)
                    for i, code in enumerate('FGH')
                    for fn in (int, str)):
    print a
```

Output:

```
(1, 'F')
('1', 'F')
(2, 'G')
('2', 'G')
(3, 'H')
('3', 'H')
```

---

Simplified loop for better readability:

```
for i, code in enumerate('FGH'):
    for fn in (int, str):
        print i, code, fn
```

Output:

```
0 F <type 'int'>
0 F <type 'str'>
1 G <type 'int'>
1 G <type 'str'>
2 H <type 'int'>
2 H <type 'str'>
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because of this `(fn(i+1), code))` the generator yields a tuple with the first item as either an int or string and the second value as a letter from `'FGHJKMNQUVXZ'`

Here is another example of it without the second for loop

```
def gen_func(text):
    for i, code in enumerate(text):
        yield i, code
        yield str(i), code

print(dict(gen_func('FGHJKMNQUVXZ')))
```

All the happens with `for fn in (int, str)` is that `fn` can then be either the built-in `int` or `str` function to convert the value of `i`.

```
int(i)
str(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is making use of that in Python class names it can also be used to call the constructor function that returns an instance of that class.  For example:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(value):
        self.value = value

a = A(10)
```

Note that `A` is both a class name and can also be used as a Python `callable`. The neat thing here is that `int` and `str` can also be used in the same way!

```
z = 10
value = int(z) # Returns number 10
print isinstance(value, int) # Prints True
print isinstance(value, str) # Prints False
value = str(z) # returns '10'
print isinstance(value, int) # Prints False
print isinstance(value, str) # Prints True
```

So the second loop is using `str` and `int` as functions that return either the string or integer representation of the index in the first `for` loop. You can also imagine having written two functions like this:

```
def as_int(value):
    return int(value)

def as_str(value):
    return str(value)
```

And then writing the `for` loop like this:

```
dict((fn(i+1), code)
for i, code in enumerate('FGHJKMNQUVXZ')
for fn in (as_int, as_str))
 # This second loop loops over the 2-element tuple 
 # whose contents are the two functions `as_int` and `as_str`
```

As a long-form version of the example.