# How do you turn probabilities that don't sum up to 1 into ones that do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you turn probabilities that don't sum up to one into probabilities that sum to one if you don't know the number of keys and the names of the keys? 
For example:

```
a = {'g' = 0.1, 'b' = 0.05, 'u' = 0.15, 'i' = 0.2}
```

To:

```
a = {'g' = 0.2, 'b' = 0.1, 'u' = 0.3, 'i' = 0.4}
```

Comment: you mean? sum the values and apply a coefficient so the sum is 1, and apply that to all keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you aim to do is called *normalization*: you calculate the `sum` and divide all elements by that sum:

```
total_inv = 1.0/sum(a.values())
for key,val in a.items():
    a[key] = val*total_inv
```

Or even shorter (like [@Jean-FrançoisFabre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193044/how-do-you-turn-probabilities-that-dont-sum-up-to-one-into-probabilities-that-s/42193080#comment71548118_42193080) says) use *dict comprehension*:

```
total_inv = 1.0/sum(a.values())
a = {k:v*total_inv for k,v in a.items()}
```

but this will **construct a new dictionary**, so references to the old dictionary are not updated.

In the code we calculate `1.0/sum(..)` because a division usually is more expensive than a multiplication and thus can gain some efficiency with that.

Comment: `a = {k:v*total_inv for k,v in a.items()}`

Answer (score 1):

Following answers for making dictionaries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python), this should solve your problem:

```
a = {'g':0.1, 'b': 0.05, 'u':0.15, 'i': 0.2}
total = sum(a.values())
new_dict = dict((key, value/total) for (key, value) in a.items())
```

Comment: just use a dictionary comprehension, no need to complicate things. (See Jean's comment on the other answer).

Comment: `zip(a.keys(), a.values())` is `a.items()`, except we may not have guarantees  for order in Py2

Comment: Both good points - edited, and see the post above for a cleaner approach.