# How to parse this JSON dict to print out a key,value pair?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

```
cow = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1179640025492630",
            "indicator": "google-analytics|UA-97996598-1",
            "type": "API_KEY"
        },
        {
            "id": "1469013519830038",
            "indicator": "google-analytics|UA-96613605-2",
            "type": "API_KEY"
        },
        {
            "id": "1459958767410551",
            "indicator": "google-analytics|UA-86399386-2",
            "type": "API_KEY"
        },
        {
            "id": "1507839102569000",
            "indicator": "google-analytics|UA-89570367-2",
            "type": "API_KEY"
        },
        {
            "id": "1276736575767341",
            "indicator": "google-analytics|UA-69774312-4",
            "type": "API_KEY"
        },
        {
            "id": "1292251910882451",
            "indicator": "google-analytics|UA-93952538-3",
            "type": "API_KEY"
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "after": "NQZDZD",
            "before": "MAZDZD"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to extract the "id": "1179640025492630" from the data dictionary.

I have tried to use a for loop like:

```
for i in cow['data']:
    for key,value in i:
        if(i == 'id'):
            print key,value
        else:
            pass
```

it gives me a value error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dict.py", line 14, in <module>
    for key,value  in ['data']:
  ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

And if I use `.iteritems` I get an `AttributeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dict.py", line 14, in <module>
    for key,value   in ['data'].iteritems:
  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: Your error message is not from the code you posted. The error message shows you calling `['stuff'].iteritems` which isn't in the code you posted and isn't semantically correct. Update one or the other.

Comment: `for key,value in i.items()` if `i` is a dictionary. Else you only get the keys.

Comment: What do you mean by "extract" them?

Comment: @martineau i want to print out the id.

Comment: @annmarie124: Sorry that doesn't really make sense—just `print("1179640025492630")` if that's what you want.

Comment: @martineau i want it to pull out the key: value pairs of 'id's' from the data dictionary if that helps.

Comment: @annmarie124: Oh, so you just want to print all the id's.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is print all values associated with the `id`s:

```
for thing in cow["data"]:
    print(thing["id"])
```

Output:

```
1179640025492630
1469013519830038
1459958767410551
1507839102569000
1276736575767341
1292251910882451
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a cleaner solution that using nested `for` loops, you can use python's `map` function to iterate over all of the dictionaries in `data` and only take the `id` values.

```
>>> list(map(lambda d: 'id: {}'.format(d['id']), cow['data']))
['id: 1179640025492630', 'id: 1469013519830038', 'id: 1459958767410551', 'id: 1507839102569000', 'id: 1276736575767341', 'id: 1292251910882451']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exctract the *id* field, use a mapping function:

```
map(lambda item: ("id", item["id"]), cow["data"])
```

and you'll get a list of tuples (be aware that py3 map is lazy and you'll force evaluation to list).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can combine [list](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) and [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python) comprehension, which might be easier to process along the line.

```
result = [{k:v for k,v in dikt.items() if k == "id"} for dikt in cow['data']]
```

gives you

> [{'id': '1179640025492630'}, {'id': '1469013519830038'}, {'id': '1459958767410551'}, {'id': '1507839102569000'}, {'id': '1276736575767341'}, {'id': '1292251910882451'}]

And you can print it out like so:

```
print "\n".join([i['id'] for i in result])
```