# Python loop statement postposition explaination

Tags: python, python-2.7

Come from the Ruby world, Python for me is a little “stange”. Someone's code:

```
the_dict = {"a": 1, "b":2}
another_dict = {
    key: val 
    for key, val in the_dict.iteritems()
}
print(another_dict)
```

returns:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

The for .. in loop is postpostion. However I can not find any Python doc about this, can anyone give some explanation on this?

PS: Glad to see something familiar in Python cause in Ruby we often do " a = somthing if codition.valid?"

Comment: It's a "dict comprehension": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python

Comment: Cool, thant helps.