# Combine dictionary according to key value in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Let us Assume, I have a key value pair in python, such as the following.

```
a = {'44': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], '43': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]}
```

now I want to combine these values with:

```
b = {'44': ['test1'], '43': ['test2']}
```

How can I do the output below in python?

```
c = {'44': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 'test1], '43': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0,'test2']}
```

Comment: Possible repetition of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension like this (as of Python 2.7+):

```
c = {k: a[k] + b[k] for k in a}
```

This assumes that the same keys exist in both `a` and `b`.
If that's not the case, it's possible to work around that if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are based on the assumption that all dictionaries involved have all the same keys. If you aren't sure that this is the case, I recommend using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for d in (a,b):
    for key, value in d.items():
        result[key].append(value)
```

Additionally, this solution works for any number of dictionaries. Simply add all dictionaries you want to merge, to the tuple `(a,b)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {'44': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], '43': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]}
b = {'44': ['test1'], '43': ['test2']}

c = {}

for v in a:
    c[v] = a[v]+b[v]
```

Output:

```
{'44': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 'test1'], '43': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 'test2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) with dictionary comprehension to achieve that in one-line code like below:

```
c = {k: v for k, v in zip(a.keys(), (v1 + v2 for v1, v2 in zip(a.values(), b.values())))}
```

**Output:**

```
>>> c
{'44': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 'test1'], '43': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 'test2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing coming to my mind is :

```
c = {k: a.get(k, []) + b.get(k, []) for k in {*a.keys(), *b.keys()}}
```

This should work even if some keys are missing in one dict. I think this only works on the newer versions of python 3 though.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that `a` and `b` contain the same keys. Then you can simply use the dict comprehension ([Create a dictionary with list comprehension in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python)):

```
c = {x: a[x] + b[x] for x in a}
```

If you don't know whether `b` has the same keys, you can also test for that:

```
c = {x: a[x] + b[x] for x in a if x in b}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
a = {'44': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], '43': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]}
b = {'44': ['test1'], '43': ['test2']}
final_data = {c:a[c]+b[c] for c, d in a.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'44': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 'test1'], '43': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 'test2']}
```

If you need to generate the "test1", "test2" values, etc, you can try this:

```
l1 = {}
for c, d in a.items():
   if d not in l1.values(): 
       l1["test{}".format(len(l1)+1)] = d

print(l1)
```

Output:

```
{'test1': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'test2': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]}
```