# python 3 nested comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, nested-loops

Is there a smart list/dictionary comprehension way of getting the intended output below give the following:

```
import numpy as np
freq_mat = np.random.randint(2,size=(4,5));
tokens = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
labels = ['X', 'S', 'Y', 'S'];
```

The intended output for freq_mat

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

should like the following:

```
[({'a': True, 'b': False, 'c': False, 'd': True, 'e': True}, 'X'),
 ({'a': False, 'b': False, 'c': False, 'd': False, 'e': True}, 'S'),
 ({'a': True, 'b': False, 'c': True, 'd': True, 'e': False}, 'Y'),
 ({'a': False, 'b': True, 'c': False, 'd': False, 'e': False}, 'S')]
```

Comment: have a look here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/1747827/7352806]

Comment: Could you explain what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Something is odd with your original code: you're setting `d[key] = val>0` repeatedly for the same `key` but different `val`. This either not doing what you want or it's wasting a lot of work. What do you expect `featureset` to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you note in your updated post, your original code doesn't work quite right: it adds the same value for every key in a given row - all `True` or all `False`. The simplest correction to your original code would be this:

```
featureset = []
for row, label in zip(freq_mat, labels):
    d = dict()
    for key, val in zip(tokens, row): # The critical bit
        d[key] = val>0            
    featureset.append((d,label))
```

A more streamlined version, but one that's still quite a bit more readable, I think, than the single-comprehension approach:

```
featureset = []
for row, label in zip(freq_mat, labels):
    d = {key: val > 0 for key, val in zip(tokens, row)}
    featureset.append((d, label))
```

Or for the one-liner:

```
featureset = [({key:val>0 for key, val in zip(tokens, row)}, label)
    for row, label in zip(freq_mat, labels)]
```

Personally I'd probably go with the second approach, a compromise of concision and readability. But that's up to you, of course!

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I just worked it out with a fresh brain this morning :-). Marking your answer correct with sincere apologies to Stephen above.

Answer (score 1):

You can collapse that code to:

#### Code:

```
featureset = [
    ({key: val > 0 for val in row for key in tokens}, label)
    for row, label in zip(freq_mat, labels)]
```

#### Test Code:

```
freq_mat = np.random.randint(2, size=(4, 5));
tokens = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
labels = ['X', 'S', 'Y', 'S'];

featureset2 = []
for row, label in zip(freq_mat, labels):
    d = dict()
    for key in tokens:
        for val in row:
            d[key] = val > 0
    featureset2.append((d, label))

featureset = [
    ({key: val > 0 for val in row for key in tokens}, label)
    for row, label in zip(freq_mat, labels)]

assert featureset == featureset2
```

Comment: Like the original code, this does a lot of unnecessary work: `{key:val > 0 for val in row for key in tokens}` is exactly equivalent to `{key:row[-1]>0 for key in tokens}` (if `row` is non-empty, of course). I suspect there's some confusion on the poster's side.

Comment: Ah, so I was quite close. Thanks for your help Stephen, this works for me.
@Nathan, I have added the intended output to the question. Basically, I am working on BoW feature construction from a text feature, stored in a Pandas dataframe. The above should allow me to use the output from CountVectorizer to construct featuresets for NLTK classifiers. This probably is a bit convoluted way of doing it but several other solutions I looked at seemed a bit involved and didn't work for me. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: My apologies friends. You are right Nathan, my code is not doing what it is supposed to do. I have edited my original post to remove confusion. Sorry again for the confusion. 

@Stephen, I will mark your answer correct if you could kindly amend your response for the revised question.