# Python3: How to make dictionary from list using 'dict' and 'zip'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm learning Python3. I can't solve a problem... Please help me.
I could **input 2 different strings**(One is consisted with **string** another is consisted with **float**).
I'd like to make a dictionary from 2 different lists.
I made first one for **key**, another is for **value**.

```
input1 = list(map(str, input().split()))
input2 = list(map(float, input().split()))

# output = dict(zip(input1), (input2))
output = dict((input1, input2) for (input1[i], input2[i]) in range(0, len(input2)))
print(output)
```

*Don't care too much that comment(#)*
I found a post may help my probelm from stack overflow.
[Create a dictionary with list comprehension in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python)

I did my best but I coudn't solve this...(New one below # comment, It is what I tried to reading that post)

Thanks to read my question!

Comment: I suggest reading up on [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function

Comment: @NestorYanchuk: Why do you think that a delimter for [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) would be needed?

Comment: @Matthias, you are right. My mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a `dict` from list of tuples:

```
numbers = [1,2,3]
words = ['one', 'two', 'three']

dict(zip(numbers, words))
```

It's just a matter of switching places of `numbers` and `words` lists, and you have keys/values switched too.

Comment: Thank a lot... It looks like I thought that probelm too conffuse to solve.