# Assigning objects to dict with member as key

Tags: python

I'm using a dict to ensure that I have only one copy of a Path in my system:

```
 for obj in obj_list:
     obj_dict[obj.fullname]=obj
```

Is there some more efficient way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Not really.  This method will be slower than a linear search for smaller data sets, but will be much faster for larger data sets as testing for a duplicate entry is a hash table lookup.

The time complexity of your code is amortized O(n) (the best you can hope to achieve when you have to process every item in a data set), while doing a linear search is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 0):

Try obj in obj_list

like this 'a' in x

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/membership_operators_example.htm

Comment: This will perform a linear search, which has `O(n)` time.  OP's code has `O(1)` time for testing for the presence of an item.

Answer (score 0):

look at [create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python)

List comprehension is much faster - I assume this is meant by efficency.

Comment: List comprehension will be less code but not faster. It has higher memory complexity as it needs to hold an extra copy of the entire data set in memory. With a sufficiently large data set, this will result in unnecessary swapping.

Comment: Also, I'm not certain how to apply it in this case.  It seems to expect a list of tuples.

Comment: list comprehension perform better here because you don’t need to load the append attribute of the list and call it as a function! I do not get the thing with the swapping? We are purely in memory.