# Python dictionary remove dots

Tags: python, mongodb, csv

i have multiple CSVs which i need to import into MangoDB. These csv's have a dot in the header which is failing when i insert them into MangoDB. apparently they dont allow dots in the keys. How can i remove the dots? i cannot modify the CSV as the csv's are loaded at runtime

```
  df = pd.read_csv(filepath) #csv file which you want to import
  records_ = df.to_dict(orient = 'records')
  print(records_)
  result = db.matchstats.insert_many(records_ )
```

Comment: [Pandas has excellent documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#splitting-and-replacing-strings) - and methods to replace/transform strings.  If you search I imagine there are a number of SO Q&A's regarding removing or replacing substrings in Pandas DataFrames or Series.

Comment: *MangoDB* == MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

You are converting your data to a dictionary here:

```
records_ = df.to_dict(orient = 'records')
```

Thus, you can just apply a [dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python#1747827) (I am assuming operating on the dictionary `keys` here, as per your question.) You can just use a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) to replace individual items.

For example (note that this assumes Py 3):

```
import re
records_ = {re.sub(r"\.+", "", k):v for k,v in records_.items()} # replace one or more stops using re.sub
```

However, the overall approach of just replacing dots seems dangerous as it can lead to duplicate keys / dropped keys; you might reconsider it based on your data.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. i'm getting the error 'list' object has no attribute 'items' now.

Comment: ah indeed, the `to_dict` returns a list when you use the 'records' setting. Can you do a `print (_records[0])` and reproduce results here, indicating which item you want to convert?