# Does DFS take default primitives if we dont specify any?

Tags: featuretools

1. if we don't specify the list of primitives to use in DFS, will it take all primitives possible?
2. if i give only agg_primitives list and not trans primiives, will it consider aggregated list that i provided and for trans, all the default primitives ? or it won't do any trans primitives at all and use only agg?

Comment: Also if we dont specify the list of categorical variables explicitly while creating an entity, does it automatically deduce them? Should we decide to override and we have too many categorical types to write in a dictionary format manually, can we pass them as a single list?

Comment: This comment seems to have two new unrelated questions. The first could be asked as a SO question along the lines of "When loading data into an entity, which variables have variable_type Categorical?" For the second, you're probably looking to turn your list into a dict comprehension as in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python . See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for guidelines on what to write as a SO question.

Answer (score 2):

DFS in Featuretools does use a set a of default primitives if you do not specify them

The default aggregation primitives are `['sum', 'std, 'max', 'skew', 'min', 'mean', 'count', 'percent_true', 'n_unique', 'mode']`

The default transformation primitives are `['day', 'year', 'month', 'weekday', 'haversine', 'num_words', 'num_characters']`

If you provide a value for one but not the other, the default list is used. If you do not want any primitives to be used pass an empty list.

You can find this information in the Featuretools documentation [here](https://docs.featuretools.com/generated/featuretools.dfs.html#featuretools.dfs).