# What does "char_to_ix = { ch:i for i,ch in enumerate(sorted(chars)) }" do?

Tags: python, dictionary

What does this line of code do?

```
char_to_ix = { ch:i for i,ch in enumerate(sorted(chars)) }
```

What is the meaning of `ch:i`?

Comment: It is `dict` comprehesion. Here https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/ :)

Comment: char_to_ix will represent a dictionary containing item as key and their position as a value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a dictionary with comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-comprehension)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a dict comprehension as mentioned in by @han solo

the final product is a dict 
it will sort your `chars`, attach a number in ascending order to them, and then use each character as the key to that numerical value
here's an example:

`chars = ['d', 'a', 'b']`
`sorted(chars)` => `['a', 'b', 'd']`
`enumerate(sorted(chars))` => a generator object that unrolls into `[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'd')]`
**`char_to_ix = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'd': 2}`**

Answer (score 2):

It is dict comprehension.
ch - it is key in dictionary,
i - value for that key.

Dictionary syntax is

```
dict = {
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2
}
```

With your code you will generate `key: value` pairs from enumerated chars.
Key would be an element of sorted list of chars.
Value - index of that element