# Trying to compare two lists, find the equal values and replace them with the index of the other list, but it is not working

Tags: python, list, for-loop, comparison, substitution

Basically, I have a list that contains all the possibles values of the second list. For example:

First list (Possible values):

```
list1 = ['cat','dog','pig']
```

Second list:

```
list2 = ['dog','cat','cat','cat','dog','pig','cat','pig']
```

I want to compare those lists and substitute all the strings in the second list to the index of the first one.

So expect something like this:

```
list2 = [1,0,0,0,1,2,0,2]
```

I've tried it in several different ways. The first one, although it worked, was not an intelligent method. Since if the first list had a huge variety of possible values, this strategy would not be functional to code.

That was the first solution:

```py
list3 = []
for i in list2:
    if i == 'cat':
        i = 0
        list3.append(i)
    elif i == 'dog':
        i = 1
        list3.append(i)
    elif i == 'pig':
        i = 2
        list3.append(i)
    list2 = list3


print(list2)
```

**output**

```py
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2]
```

But I want a solution that works in a huge variety of possible values without having to code each test.

So I tried this (and other failed attempts), but it isn't working

```py
for i in list2:
    for j in list1:
        if i == j:
            i = list1.index(j)
```

Comment: what is the contents of `list2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are simply replacing `i` on each iteration. You want to create a *list* and append the result from `list1.index(j)` to it on each iteration:

```
 l = []
for i in list2:
    for j in list1:
        if i == j:
            l.append(list1.index(j))
```

---

Note that this can be simplified with a list comprehension:

```
[list1.index(i) for i in list2]
# [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2]
```

---

Note that for a lower complexity solution, you can create a dictionary mapping strings to index, and simply create a list by looking up with the strings in `list2`, as in @blhshing's answer.

---

Some reads you might find useful:

- [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)
- [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [string — Common string operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Comment: Note that using `list.index` in a loop costs *O(n^2)* in time complexity.

Comment: Yes just adapting from OP's code.  For a better performing solution looking up on a dict as in your solution is much better @blhsing

Answer (score 0):

The `i` you get by iterating the list does not reflect changes  back into the list. Hence no change.

---

Create a dictionary that mapps animal to index position.

Use a list comprehension to create a new list by replacing animals of `list2` its lookup-index:

```
list1 = ['cat','dog','pig']

lookup = {animal:index for index,animal in enumerate(list1)}

list2 = ['dog','cat','cat','cat','dog','pig','cat','pig']

result = [lookup.get(what) for what in list2]

print(result) # [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2]
```

Doku:

- [enumerate(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- [Create a dictionary with list comprehension in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension-in-python) (creation of the lookup)
- [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict comprehension to create a mapping dict that maps keys to indices using the `enumerate` function, and then map items in `list2` to the values of the mapping dict:

```
mapping = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(list1)}
list(map(mapping.get, list2))
```

This returns:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one `for loop` and one `if-statement` that is easy to understand.

```
list1 = ['cat','dog','pig']
list2 = ['dog','cat','cat','cat','dog','pig','cat','pig']

for i,item in enumerate(list2):
    if item in list1:
        list2[i] = list1.index(item)       

# list2 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2]
```