# One liner : create dict one line

Tags: python

Hi I am wondering is it possible to return dict in one line of this code ?

```
languages = {}
for folder_with_languages in folders_with_languages:
    name, files = get_files_from_dir(folder_with_languages)
    languages[name] = files
```

I was trying really bad , I could not  manage it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a dictionary with list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension)

Comment: What did you try, exactly, what was the difficulty you ran in to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should:

```
languages = {name:files for name, files in map(get_files_from_dir, folders_with_languages)}
```