# Assigning Key, Value in a Dictionary Comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around Dictionary Comprehension.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817/create-a-dictionary-with-list-comprehension) states the correct syntax is `{key: value for (key, value) in iterable}`.

Does that mean I cannot take the below code and create a more elegant oneliner to create a dictionary from an `os.listdir`?

```
import os

d = {}
for item in os.listdir(path):
    d[item] = os.listdir(path + "/" + item + "/urls")
```

I am trying to create a dictionary key from the path, then create values from the static subfolder `/urls`.

`{'foo': ['bar','bah'], 'foo1': ['bar1', 'bah1']}`

I've tried variations of `a = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(os.listdir(path))}` but am unclear based off my review if it's even possible via Dictionary Comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
d = {item: os.listdir(path + "/" + item + "/urls") for item in os.listdir(path)}
```

Explanation:

For each element returned by `os.listdir(path)` (named `item` in my case), the following *key: value* pair is created where:

1. key - item
2. value - the expression `os.listdir(path + "/" + item + "/urls")`

Comment: Any chance you can edit the answer to Explain like I'm 5? I'd like to know where conceptually I don't understand the syntax of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should work when you have defined `path`:

```
d = {item: os.listdir(path + "/" + item + "/urls") for item in os.listdir(path)}
```

Only problem is to check for `FileNotFoundError` exceptions when the computed path doesn't exist. So if you risk producing invalid paths, I'd recommend you go with the original syntax.