# Extracting a (sub)dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I would like to extract a sub-dictionary from an existing one consisting of a series of keys whose values are all numpy arrays of shape (N, 3) or (N). The sub-dictionary should contain the same keys whose values will be arrays of shape (m,3) or (m), m<N, where the m values are obtained by applying some criterion to one of the key:values pairs.

Here a very simple Python code to exemplify my question.

```
import sys
import numpy as np

t1 = np.arange(0,30,0.5)
t1n = t1.reshape(20,3)

t2 = np.random.rand(20,1)

dtest = dict(p1=t1n, p2=t2)

ind_ok = np.where(dtest['p2'][dtest['p2'] > 0.7])
sub_dtest = dict(p1=dtest['p1'][ind_ok,:], p2=dtest['p2'][ind_ok,:])
```

---

This is a simple dictionary having only two pairs, and I extract the rows from the second pairs veryfying some criterion, e.g. that the values are larger than 0.7. Then I construct the desired sub-dictionary (sub_dtest) by directly indexing each key:values pair with the extracted indexes.
When I have many pairs in my dictionary I have to repeat the value assignment for each of them: is there a more elegant way in Python to accomplish this task?

The code above is a simplified version of what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Use [a dictionary comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1747817/364696) (dictcomp for short) based on either the fixed set of keys you care about:

```
sub_dtest = {k: dtest[k][ind_ok,:] for k in ('p1', 'p2')}
```

or using all key/value pairs in the original `dict`:

```
sub_dtest = {k: arr[ind_ok,:] for k, arr in dtest.items()}
```

The first option requires listing out all the keys you care about, the second is exhaustive, though you could add a condition to exclude some keys, e.g. if you wanted all keys but `'pbad'` and `'pworse'`, you could change it to:

```
sub_dtest = {k: arr[ind_ok,:] for k, arr in dtest.items() if k not in {'pbad', 'pworse'}}
```

expanding the `set` of excluded keys as needed (or reducing to just `if k != 'pbad'` if you only want to exclude a single key).